# Javascript incapable of getting element's max-height via element.style.maxHeight

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am making a simple accordion menu in javascript. I'd like to be able to set the compact and expanded heights for the elements via the css max-height and min-height values. For some reason, when I try to retrieve the min-height and max-height of the elements in javascript for animation purposes, I get an empty string rather than, for instance, "500px" like it should. The max-height value is set in css, e.g.
`#id {
min-height: 40px;
max-height: 500px;
}`
is all set up, but when I put a debugging mechanism in my javascript such as
`alert( item.style.minHeight );`
it pops up an empty alert box. This happens in Firefox 3.6.2 and IE 8. Does anybody know why javascript refuses to be able to get an element's minHeight and maxHeight?

Answer (score 10):

The [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/element.style) property lets you know only the CSS properties that were defined as *inline* in that element, you should get the *computed style*, is not so easy to do it in a cross-browser way, as others said, IE has its own way, through the `element.currentStyle` property, the DOM Level 2 *standard* way, implemented by other browsers is the [`document.defaultView.getComputedStyle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) method.

However there are differences between the IE way and the standard way, for example, the IE [`element.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(VS.85).aspx) property expect that you access the CCS property names composed of two or more words in *camelCase* (e.g. `maxHeight`, `fontSize`, `backgroundColor`, etc), the standard way expects the properties with the words separated with dashes (e.g. `max-height`, `font-size`, `background-color`, etc).

Also, the IE `element.currentStyle` will return all the sizes in the unit that they were specified, (e.g. 12pt, 50%, 5em), the standard way will compute the actual size in pixels.

I made some time ago a cross-browser function that allows you to get the computed styles in a cross-browser way:

```
function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
  var value, defaultView = (el.ownerDocument || document).defaultView;
  // W3C standard way:
  if (defaultView && defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    // sanitize property name to css notation
    // (hypen separated words eg. font-Size)
    styleProp = styleProp.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();
    return defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  } else if (el.currentStyle) { // IE
    // sanitize property name to camelCase
    styleProp = styleProp.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter) {
      return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
    value = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    // convert other units to pixels on IE
    if (/^\d+(em|pt|%|ex)?$/i.test(value)) { 
      return (function(value) {
        var oldLeft = el.style.left, oldRsLeft = el.runtimeStyle.left;
        el.runtimeStyle.left = el.currentStyle.left;
        el.style.left = value || 0;
        value = el.style.pixelLeft + "px";
        el.style.left = oldLeft;
        el.runtimeStyle.left = oldRsLeft;
        return value;
      })(value);
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

The above function is not perfect for some cases, for example for colors, the standard method will return colors in the *rgb(...)* notation, on IE they will return them as they were defined.

Check this [example](http://jsbin.com/okiqa).

Answer (score 4):

```
currentStyle for IE, getComputedStyle elsewhere.
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(who,'').getPropertyValue('min-height');
```

Might as well learn it, IE 9 will support getComputedStyle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `currentStyle` instead...

```
alert(item.currentStyle.minHeight);
```

The `style` property refers to what has been set by Javascript, as opposed to the inherited CSS.  Libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) address this internally (among other countless annoyances).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend jQuery.

Just add jQuery to your page, then you can get and set CSS attributes dynamically and in a cross browser way (it eliminates a LOT of headaches). Here's the syntax:

```
/*  this outer '$(function() { innerContent });'
    is jQuery's helpful function that executes when all
    the elements in your HTML document are ready to
    be accessed (if you executed code without this,
    when you try to find the element you want to find,
    it might not have been created yet, and so your code
    will have no effect on that element)  */
$(function() {

    //  get CSS data
    var currentMinHeight = $('#idOfElement').css('min-height');
    var currentMaxHeight = $('#idOfElement').css('max-height');

    //  set CSS data
    $('#idOfElement').css('min-height', '999px');
    $('#idOfElement').css('max-height', '999px');

});
```

Be sure not to forget the # in front of the element's id (this is how jQuery knows you want the element that has that id)

There are ways you avoid the redundant function calls I made above and accomplish the same thing. jQuery.com will get you rolling like a cross browser pro in no time!

Comment: just remember anything done in jQuery can be done in vanilla JS so avoiding adding the whole library for this one issue is possible