# Why are all of my DOM element properties coming back as empty strings?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

There must be something simple I'm missing. I'm using only vanilla Javascript to return DOM element properties. The problem is, I'm only getting empty strings when I try to get any style property from my DOM elements.

Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child js-child">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   right: -220px;
   top: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Some JS code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("js-child")[0];
   var rightPosition = element.style.right;
});
```

When I put in a debugger and check the value, `rightPosition = ""`.

It should be `rightPosition = "-220px"`. No matter what property I'm trying to get, it all comes back as `""` (I've tried checking the display, top property, and several others).

I want to run a simple if statement, `if (rightPosition === "-220px")`, but it's always coming back as an empty string, so the if statement doesn't check out.

When I look in the chrome inspector, all of the CSS is set properly and working.

Any ideas as to why I'm only getting empty strings?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to console log element.style?

Comment: Yes, every property is an empty string.

Comment: You need to get the computed style of the element instead of direct CSS style.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had never heard of computed style before. You guys are the best!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue`. `element.style` will refer to the `style` attribute on the element (inline styles), and your CSS isn't inline.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("js-child")[0];
   var rightPosition = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('right');
  console.log(rightPosition)
});
```

```css
.parent {
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   right: -220px;
   top: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child js-child">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The style property of an element represents the inline style attribute of the element's html. What you're looking for is the computed style

```
var rightPosition = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('right');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get external css from JS directly. Use `getComputedStyle` and then `getPropertyValue`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("js-child")[0];
   var rightPosition = window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue('right');
   console.log(rightPosition);
});
```

```css
.parent {
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   right: -220px;
   top: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child js-child">
   Hello world
   </div>
</div>
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558076/2427065

Answer (score -2):

Presa CTRL + F5 to clear the cash
Then try, if it doesn't work, try to set the variables outside the addEventListener function just to test the code, Also delete the var keyword to set the variables global .. and check :)