# Why I can't get these css properties on loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

could you tell me why I cant get these css properties when I load the page?

[code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd6Kd/4/)

**javascript**:

```
function aviso(){
    alert("top: "+document.getElementById("divRojo").style.top);
    alert("position: "+document.getElementById("divRojo").style.position);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #divRojo {
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background:red;
                left:200px;
                top:200px;
                position:static;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="aviso()">
    <div id="divRojo">
        Div Rojo
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `DOMElement.style` property contains inline styles -- it does not contain style rules applied via CSS.

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to get the applied styles:

```
var el = document.getElementById("divRojo");
alert(window.getComputedStyle(el).top);
alert(window.getComputedStyle(el).position);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVJDH/1/)