# HTML5 CSS Class. Is there now way to inspect the values of a css class?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am try to do something I thought was trivial but appears impossible: print the values of a css class associated with a div. Should be easy. Not for moi.

Your task: Using console.log() echo the value of top (or left or height, etc.) for the class associated with a div.

What am I missing?

### UPDATE

Ok, more context:

Using pure Javascript - no JQuery I have done the following to create a div. insert it in the DOM, and assign a class to it:

```
// css class name
var sequenceDivClassName="igv-sequence-div",

classyDiv = document.createElement('div');
classyDiv.setAttribute('id', classyDivID);

parentDiv = document.getElementById(parentDivID);
parentDiv.appendChild(classyDiv);

document.getElementById(classyDivID).className = sequenceDivClassName;
```

Here is what the CSS class looks like:

```
.igv-sequence-div {
    color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width:100%;
}
```

I am doing all this in a Qunit unit test and I would like to do an assertion on the height. How do I access the `height` field of the class so I can using it in an assertion - `equal(...)`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use the console rather than the browser's web inspector?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: You can get the computed styles, but I'm not sure you can isolate it to a specific class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “css class”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got it. Can you use jQuery?
It makes it super easy.
I did it with an alert. I dont like console.logs. Personal preference.

```
alert($(".whatever").css("left"));
```

[Fiddle Bro!](http://jsfiddle.net/PAW7X/1/)

Comment: thanks for this. +1 for the jsfiddle. So, our project is trying to remain pure Javascript. Damn that looks trivs in jQuery. Maybe we should relent. Cheers.

Comment: That will get the left property of the computed style of the first element which is a member of the `whatever` class. That style may or may not come from a rule-set with a `.whatever` class selector on it. The same effect can be achieved with `getComputedStyle` as per my answer.

Comment: I hear ya @Quentin. Gettin' there. The stark difference between jQuery's obvious programming model and the pure Javascript gymnastic weirdness is one helluva selling point to throw in the towel and go all jQuery. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

HTML classes do not have CSS rules directly associated with them.

CSS rule-sets come with selectors. These could be made up of a single simple selector (which might be a class selector) or multiple selectors (or even groups of multiple selectors).

Multiple rule-sets can have selectors that match the same element. The CSS rules that actually apply to a given element are determined by a combination of the cascade and inheritance.

You can find out the particular rules associated with an element using [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

You can get a list of all the rules associated with a document by looping over [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) then looping over the `rules` property of the each of the results. You can then examine the `selectorText` property to see if it matches a given class selector.

Comment: Not parsing this Quentin. I have a div. The div has a CSS class. I want to print a member of the class. This must me easy, no?

Comment: The div does not have a CSS class. It is a member of an HTML class (or maybe more than one, or none). There might be a CSS rule-set with a class selector that matches one of the classes on the element. Or multiple classes. Or multiple rule-sets that match.

Comment: since I am leaning to jQuery I went with Aaron's answer although your solution is the correct pure Javascript way to go.