# Is it possible to fetch an element's css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium's webdriverJS to automate some things on an html5 page.
I had to use a css selector for putting it into a function.
I can fetch some elements with xpath like this:

```
var complexXpath = "//*/div/a";     /* not the xpath, but an example here */
var element = mydriver.findElement(mywebdriver.By.xpath(complexXpath));
```

Is it possible to fetch now the css of that element, so I can use it into another javascript function that uses only css ? Something like

```
var b = element.getCSS();
```

Comment: you can go with: `.getComputedStyle()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Comment: What "CSS"? The selector, or some style(s)?

Comment: the selector, not the style

Comment: What selector? There are many different selectors that can match any given element. There can be multiple such selectors in a single stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get all classes of an object, use `element.classList`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XWUQ3/

```
<div id="first" class="one two three hi"></div>
alert(document.getElementById("first").classList);
```

It even implements: `.contains(x), .add(x), .remove(x), .toggle(x)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList