# Javascript change width of image onclick

Tags: javascript, events

I'm a complete noob when it comes to javascript. Would there be anyway to change an image after it is clicked, some way to trigger a js function to change the css. It would have to be triggered by an event and something other than onclick, onfocus probably.

```
<style>
    #pic {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src='nope.jpg' id='pic' onclick="mouseOver()"></img>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById('pic').style.width="400px";
    document.getElementById('pic').style.height="400px";
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: based on your example no JS is required.  look into css3 transitions on hover

Comment: It would have to be js though, a mouse click event would trigger all the changes.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
function mouseOver() {
   document.getElementById('image').style.height = "400px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First i edited the question , because the function was not defined correctly .

Second :

to access the height property of any element , you should use `style.height` , and should add "px" to the value.

please spend more time searching for answers , instead of posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the JS to this:

```
var image =  document.getElementById('image');

function mouseOver() {
    image.style.height="600px";
}

image.onclick = mouseOver;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting values you can use directly style attribute, but remember that asking for them is a greater problem:

Please refer to this one:
[Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<style>
#pic {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>   
<img
       width="100"
       onmouseOver="this.width=400; this.height=400"
       onclick="this.width=100"
       alt="RESIZE IMAGE"
       id='pic'
       src='nope.jpg'
    />
```

just copy and edit the image tag code as needed