# Changing an icon image on click

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, background

Here is what I want to do. There are four icons, and when we click on an icon, its background image should change.
When we click again on it, the first image should come again.
Here is my code. Thanks for your help ; I spent some time but I didn't find the solution: the "if" block doesn't not recognize the value of the background. Thanks a lot for helping me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
    #image1, #image2, #image3, #image4 {
    background: url('icon1.png');
        width:24px;
    height:24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="image1" onclick="change(this)"></p>
    <p id="image2" onclick="change(this)"></p>
    <p id="image3" onclick="change(this)"></p>
    <p id="image4" onclick="change(this)"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function change(element) {
        if(element.style.background == "url('icon1.png')") {
            element.style.background = "url('icon2.png')";
        } else {
            element.style.background = "url('icon1.png')";
        }
    }       
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on this site. I'll try to correct it. But you should more try to resolve my problem than say that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Comment: @user3601480 I removed the -1 after you edited the title. No worries, elcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I'll be more attentive next time.

Comment: I think that : 

if(element.style.background == "url('icon1.png')") { 

doesn't work. The if boucle can't get the value...

Comment: FYI, "boucle" isn't an English word.

Comment: @Juhana I'm guessing he meant "if statement".  In french, "boucle" is a loop.  Maybe user3601480 is confusing an if statement and a loop or maybe it's in another language...

Comment: Sorry, I'm french and I try to find the good word in english !

Comment: So, I think that the if statement can't make the compare between element.style.background and "url('icon1.png')"

Comment: Yes, that is the case. [Use `getComputedStyle()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6338234).

Comment: Thanks Juhana, I'm going to try with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I gave a good explain to what I would like to do.

Comment: I would like that if icon1 is on, it is remplaced by icon2 and if icon2 is on, it is remplaced by icon1.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition wont probably result as true for the first time as background-image is applied through css class and not inline style.

**So the solution would be**

```
function change(element) {
  var imgURL = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-image");
  if(imgURL == "url('icon1.png')") {
    element.style.background = "url('icon2.png')";
  } else {
    element.style.background = "url('icon1.png')";
  }
}
```