# How to change the color of two elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie at javascript and I want change the color of elem2. But this doesn´t work:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    var elem2 = document.getElementById("test2");

    var color = elem.style.backgroundColor;
    elem2.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Any ideas? THX

Comment: I have two: 1) the JS is run before the elements are loaded; 2) the element with ID `test` doesn't have inline `background-color` style.

Comment: If you set `elem`'s color using a stylesheet (not inline), the you must use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Comment: Hi, thank you... with getComputedStyle it works very well and so how I wanted it. Does it mean that my approach above is only working for inline elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var elem2 = document.getElementById('test2');    

var color = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('background-color');
elem2.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

**[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/hyH4v/)**

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is correct.

If block with id "test" has attribute "style" with backgroundColor, written inline, it should work. It should be something like:

```
&lt;div id="test" style="background-color: red"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
```

If you declare background-color it css style your js will not work.

However next one color identification will work in both situations:

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

So try to debug it using web-inspector.

Make sure variable "color" contains needed color - add

```
console.log(color)
```

and see result in console.

Also check "elem" and "elem2", maybe you have errors in ids.

Answer (score -1):

change this line

```
var color = elem.style.backgroundColor;
```

for this

```
var color = "red"; // or other you want #333
```

Comment: What if the desired color is that of the other element?