# Selenium background-Image validity

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby, selenium

I am creating some selenium test in ruby to check my web page.

Is there any way to check background-image is loaded or not using selenium webdriver or javascript.

there is css for background image

```
.banner {
background-image:url('http://dev.nestaway.in/assets/banner_slide1.jpg')
...  //some other attributes
}
```

And html looks like this

```
<div class = 'banner' style='width:100px; height:75px'>
   <h1>this is main heading</h1>
   <p>this is some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I know that I can check for 'img' but this doesn't work when images are in css background. For IMG tag images I can check

```
ele = document.getElementById('image_id');

return ele.complete && ele.naturalWidth > 0 && ele.naturalWidth != 'undefined'
```

Please Suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript  check this it might be helpful to you..

Comment: @AnantDabhi actually I want to check if background is loaded or not like for <img src='http://examplle.com/abc.png'> we can check if its loaded or not

Comment: Not familiar with Ruby but I would suggest the equivalent of item.GetCssValue("background-image") and checking the width of the image to understand if it has been loaded.