# JavaScript retrieving element's CSS values

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently making a basic drag and drop system and need to retrieve the `top` and `left` properties of the element being moved. If I do this:

```
var mover = document.getElementById('mover');
alert(mover.style.top);
```

Will alert nothing ( ' ' )

Is there any way of retrieving CSS values (in JS) without having to define them with JS first?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Comment: Oh cool! I'll just try it out. That was fast!

Comment: `mover.style.top` will give you the css value that was attached to the element when the DOM was rendered, it will not give you the current value.

Comment: @Cristik Really? I've never noticed that.

Comment: `mover.style.top` will return the value in style attribute, not from the *StyleSheet*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use getComputedStyle if you wish to retrieve properties that are computed rather than defined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

FROM the MDN link...

```
<script>
  function getTheStyle(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
   }
  getTheStyle();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the element as `position().top`, The css values can be retrieved as `.css("margin-top")` or `.css("top")`

```js
alert($('#mover').position().top);
alert($('#mover').css("margin-top"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mover'>dasdasD</div>
```

---

> Since you dislike jQuery, here is the solution in pure JS

**Update :**

```js
var mover = document.getElementById('mover');
alert(window.getComputedStyle(mover).getPropertyValue('margin-top'));
```

```html
  <div id='mover'>dasdasD</div>
```

---

Comment: I dislike jQuery and would rather not use it.

Comment: I'm highly doubtful that your `margin-top` approach will work.

Comment: @torazaburo You can use top too its as per need :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible `top`s to worry about:

1. The actual top position. Every element has a top resulting from the page layout, whether or not it has a computed value for the `top` property. Get this with `getBoundingClientRect`.
2. The computed value of the CSS property `top`. Get this with `getComputedStyle`, as mentioned in other answers
3. The current style value set on the element for `top`. Get this with `elt.style.top` as you attempted.

Answer (score -2):

```
var mover = document.getElementById('mover');
alert(mover.offsetTop);
alert(mover.offsetLeft);
```

Comment: He wants to retrieve the CSS values - not infer them from other values