# Is the 'getPropertyValue' method required for retrieving CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, cssom

Could you tell me why we need to use the `getPropertyValue` method if we can use only the `getComputedStyle` one?

For example, this will work, as far as I understand:

```js
var s = getComputedStyle(element, null).opacity;
```

Which is equivalent to the following:

```js
var s = getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('opacity');
```

Can we use `getComputedStyle` without `getPropertyValue`?

Comment: The 2nd argument of `getComputedStyle` is no longer required neither.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the old [DOM L2 Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties), `getPropertyValue` was not required:

> The `CSS2Properties` interface represents a convenience mechanism for
>   retrieving and setting properties within a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration).
>   The attributes of this interface correspond to all the [*properties
>   specified in CSS2*](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/propidx.html). Getting an attribute of this interface is
>   equivalent to calling the `getPropertyValue` method of the
>   [CSSStyleDeclaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) interface. Setting an attribute of this
>   interface is equivalent to calling the `setProperty` method of the
>   [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) interface.

However, implementations were not required to support it, so using `getPropertyValue` was safer.

> A conformant implementation of the CSS module is not required to
>   implement the `CSS2Properties` interface.

But according to the newer [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface), using camel-case without `getPropertyValue` must work:

> For each CSS property *property* that is a [supported CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#supported-css-property), the
>   following partial interface applies where *camel-cased attribute* is
>   obtained by running the [CSS property to IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#css-property-to-idl-attribute) algorithm for
>   *property*.
>
> ```
> partial interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
>     attribute DOMString _camel-cased attribute;
> };
> ```
>
> The *`camel-cased attribute`* attribute, on getting, must return the
>   result of invoking [`getPropertyValue()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) with the argument being the
>   result of running the [IDL attribute to CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#idl-attribute-to-css-property) algorithm for
>   *camel-cased attribute*.
>
> Setting the [*`camel-cased attribute`*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-camel-cased-attribute) attribute must invoke
>   [`setProperty()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty) with the first argument being the result of
>   running the [IDL attribute to CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#idl-attribute-to-css-property) algorithm for
>   *camel-cased attribute*, as second argument the given value, and no third argument. Any exceptions thrown must be re-thrown.

Therefore, `getPropertyValue` is no longer necessary to retrieve CSS values.

Comment: Thank you, Oriol, for your detailed answer. You have removed all my doubts about this subject. Kind regards, Philip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is for properties that can't be dot-notationed, like `background-position`. Though I suppose that brings up the question "why not use brackets notation, i.e. `getComputedStyle(element, null)['background-position']`?". It's possible they just wanted a getter method for the class (CSSStyleDeclaration).

Comment: Can't you use `.backgroundPosition`?

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. I myself wouldn't use that because its not generalizable.