# Is there a difference between getPropertyValue() and the bracket notation [] for CSSStyleDeclaration?

Tags: javascript, css

For example, we need to access `body`'s `padding-right`

```
let el = document.querySelector('body');
let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
```

Thanks to [this explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31506659/4117781), it's clear that it could be safely done by:

```
style.paddingRight
```

or

```
style.getPropertyValue('padding-right')
```

But, it seems that this also works fine:

```
style['padding-right']
```

Is there are any differences? Thx

Comment: FWIW: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration -> https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#cssstylesheet

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/q/31506401/2864740) talks about historic and current guarantees wrt. the object models.

Comment: (Also, in JS, `x["y"]` behaves the *same* as `x.y`, where y is a valid identifier - so asking about []-notation is basically asking if the object exposes *properties* with given names.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One difference is that `getPropertyValue` is guaranteed to return a string, while with the direct property access (JavaScript's bracket or dot notation) you *could* get `undefined`. `getPropertyValue` will return the empty string in that case.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('body');
let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

console.log(style.something === style.getPropertyValue('something')); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a difference:

1) Yes

`[]` - Accessing properties using bracket notation like this: `style['padding-right']` is defined in the runtime specification of JavaScript (ECMAScript). It is a well known mechanism for accessing properties on objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

`getPropertyValue()` - is specified in the CSSOM specification as a method for accessing CSS properties from a CSS style object.

2) No - not at all for practical purposes

3) Yes and No - opinions will flare about best practices etc. It is entirely possible (although not probable) the CSSOM specification may change and store that property in some other location on the object. That would render the brackets useless in your code and break.

Answer (score -1):

Reason why `style['padding-right']` also works.

```
>function A() { this.a = 5;}
//undefined
>a = new A()
//A {a: 5}
>a['a']
//5
```

Difference already mentioned by @trincot.