# How can I use JavaScript to find if an element has position fixed?

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript I need to find an element that has position **fixed** and set its top attribute to 60px.

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div')
if(myDiv && myDiv.style.position == 'fixed') {
    myDiv.style.top = '60px';
}
```

But it doesn't work.
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: sorry that was just a type as I created the question here.

Comment: what is `doesn't work` mean? you can not find the div?

Comment: Is the code being run *after* the document has loaded, as it needs to be?

Comment: Now I know why it's not working. The element's position gets changed after it's out of the viewport. So when the document is ready, the position is not fixed yet. I need to check the element after it's out of viewport or maybe on scroll. Which solution would be better?

Comment: @user1941537 That depends on the context, and we have absolutely none of it. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: my-div element has position absolute. When you scroll the page, as soon as my-div is out of the view port its position changes to fixed and top: 0. Here I need to change the value 0 for top to 100px.

Answer (score 2):

The `element.style.prop` deals with the `inline` styles of an element, only. It is not affected by the changing of `embedded` or `external` styles (more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)). Thus, you cannot use it to get the value of a `non-inline` property.

Therefore, you need to use this :-

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div');

if (myDiv && window.getComputedStyle(myDiv).getPropertyValue('position') == 'fixed') {
    myDiv.style.top = '60px';
}
```

Refer them from here: [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue).

Or even more simply, you could simply use the `.` or the `[]` notation to get the values. You can check out the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56586496/17898569).

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div');

if (myDiv && window.getComputedStyle(myDiv).position == 'fixed') {
    myDiv.style.top = '60px';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

It will return an object with ***all*** styles, even if not explicitly defined by you, unlike the `style` property which only holds the style values which you explicitly set.

For your code, it would look like this:

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div')
if (!myDiv) return; // Early return guard to avoid calling getComputedStyle with null
const style = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv)

if (style.position === 'fixed') {
    myDiv.style.top = '60px';
}
```