# Access mozilla specific CSS property of #titlebar (chrome) "--chrome-background-color" in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, mozilla

How do you access the value of the CSS property `--chrome-background-color` that is set on `#titlebar` of the Firefox chrome in an addon from javascript?

I tried the variants:

`document.getElementById( 'titlebar' ).style.backgroundColor // undefined`
`document.getElementById( 'titlebar' ).style['--chrome-background-color] // undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

`window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementById('titlebar') ).getPropertyValue( '--chrome-background-color' )`

From: [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Lesson: don't be hasty + it works for mozilla specific chrome elements.

Comment: Wow very itneresting on that `--chrome-backbround-color` i never would have guessed that. Whey did you need that `--chrome-` part? Can't you just do the rgulard `backround-color`?

Comment: It doesn't work with `background-color`, just confirmed it. You can try it with `ctrl+shift+alt+i` and then inspect `TabsToolbar`, and remove the `--chrome` part and the background will be messed up. Remember that you are modifying the chrome, that is using XUL, not HTML for the most part.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks Centril!

Comment: Ah it seems this method makes it `getComputedStyle`, so this is just a shim for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle