# Is possible check if a div has backgroundColor without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, styles

I'm doing a Bingo without JQuery. When I generate a number, the programm change the background-color to red.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(random1);
for(var m = 0; m < elems.length; m++) {
    elems[m].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Is possible check if the div has background color?

Comment: why don't you use the same way you're assigning color to an element to check it ? `if(elems[m].style.backgroundColor)` or you can do an explicit check if it's not red or empty - `element.style.backgroundColor !== 'red'`

Comment: oh god, I forget the third symbol of comparasion

Comment: @Arkantos - what if the original background colour is set via the style sheet?

Comment: @nnnnnn.. I forgot that this won't work for styles set via style sheets. @Alexandre.. you can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript) for options like `getComputedStyle()`