# CSS style outputting empty string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get the `padding` value of an element in JavaScript. Here's how:

```
var textWrapper = document.getElementById('textWrapper');
console.log(textWrapper.children[0].style.padding);
```

It outputs an empty string, even though in the css style, the `padding` is set to `10px`. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear()

var textWrapper = document.getElementById('textWrapper');
console.log(textWrapper.children[0].style.padding);
```

```css
.text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="textWrapper">
  <div class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</div>
  <div class="text">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</div>
  <div class="text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non</div>
  <div class="text">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Element.style is the actual HTML style added to an element, not the css class. "<div class="text" style="padding: 25px;">" that would return 25px with your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.style` property gets inline CSS. Use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead.

```
el = document.getElementById('textWrapper')
style = window.getComputedStyle(el)
padding = style.getPropertyValue('padding')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works

```
window.getComputedStyle(textWrapper.children[0], null).getPropertyValue('padding')
```

Although it returns string with pixels (e.g. "10px"), not just a number.

To get pure number use parseInt() on the output (like that : parseInt("10px") )

Comment: Just as Lazar wrote just before me :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
console.clear()
var textWrapper = document.getElementById('textWrapper');
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(textWrapper.children[0]).padding);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uybv41ry/