# javascript: get css prop value with unit

Tags: javascript, css

my code like this:

```
#image_1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 3vw;  
}
```

My try: 
http://jsfiddle.net/z8k6t3fb/1/

I want get '3vw'

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You can either get the inline styles or the computed value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate `document.styleSheets`, `.cssRules`, if `.selectorText` matches element selector, select rule from `.style` property

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("image_1");
  var prop = "top";
  var styles = document.styleSheets;
  for (var j = 0; j < styles.length; j++) {
    var rules = document.styleSheets[j].cssRules;
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
      if (rules[i].selectorText === "#" + element.id) {
        console.log(rules[i].style[prop])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#image_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="image_1">hello</div>
```

Comment: Will this work even if the selector is not the same?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Here you are directly matching the `#image_id`. What if the selector in CSS was `.image img` or something? Will this solution work?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Still not following what you mean?

Comment: That's okay... `:)`

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for answer solved my problem.
functional style:
http://jsfiddle.net/sa38xpb4/3/