# Get css style from object returned by document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get the CSS style property from objects returned by the JavaScript `querySelectorAll` function, as follows:

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll(".login_window, .confirmation_message_window");
```

CSS style properties can be readily retrieved using the `style` parameter as shown below (the below is an example targeting just index 0):

```
elements[0].style
```

However this only returns style properties defined ***in-line***, or style properties defined by setting them using the same method (which works because it puts them in-line).

Unfortunately, I need to retrieve the `top` style property which is defined in a CSS file.

Normally if there were only one instance of the class I would use jQuery for this via the `.css()` function, however I can't as I don't have the DOM object separated individually like I do using the method above as there are multiple instances of the same class.

It has been suggested this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript).  As far as I can tell these answers do not provide a solution as they assume the user can provide a selector for the class, I am dealing with DOM objects provided through `document.querySelectorAll` for multiple instances of the same class.

A method similar to that suggested in the comments is to use:

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(elements[0]);
top = style.top;
```

This does work, except it returns the value in pixels, and annoyingly in the CSS in the file I have `calc(50% - 120px);` which is what I need, as I need to change just the 120px part to retain the calc component.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, I would appreciate you explaining to me how I use those solutions for the elements object in my question.  Because it doesn't answer my question as far as I can tell (I wish it did!)

Comment: You can use getComputedStyle().

var element = document.getElementById('image_1'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    top = style.getPropertyValue('top');