# Get word-spacing width in pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace, word-spacing

I'm stuck on how to find the width in pixels of one space between words. For example, if I have a sentence: `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."` and I want the width in pixels of the whitespaces (which will all be the same), is there a formula I could use? This would have to be useable across many different font families and sizes.

I saw that I could set a width using the CSS word-spacing property like the sample below, but I don't want to *set* it, I want to *get* the value. Also, I don't want to trim the whitespace either, just calculate the amount of spaces and add their total widths.

```
p { 
    word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you planning to use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, sorry for neglecting to say that...oops!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this using javascript, to return word-spacing value of the particular element with id="id", if its word-spacing style was specified:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.wordSpacing;
```

Here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_wordspacing3

Answer (score 1):

This method ended up working for me. Basically, I needed to make the whole element into a canvas, plug in the `font-size`/`font-family` property values and the text I wanted (a space). Then I was able to use `measureText()` to find the width of a space. 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.getComputedStyle` if the `word-spacing` set via CSS.

```js
var ws = document.querySelector('#ws');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(p);
ws.textContent = style.wordSpacing;
```

```css
p {
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</p>
<div>The word spacing above is: <b id="ws">0px</b></div>
```

Comment: Nice! I actually wanted to see if I could do this without setting the `word-spacing` property though.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to get a value that isn't there. Maybe you could update your question with your html, css, and js.