# Whats wrong with me code (dom+onclick+li+display)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working

```
tutorial.onclick = function(){      
    var tutorial = document.getElementById("tutorials-ul");    
    tutorial.style.display = "list-item";    
}
```

Not working

```
news.onclick = function(){    
var news = document.getElementById("news-ul");    

if(news.style.display == "none") {     
  news.style.display = "list-item";    
}

else if(news.style.display == "list-item") {    
   news.style.display = "none";
}    
}
```

Any answer or opinion is accepted.

Comment: well this question does not say what is wrong.... working/not working tells us nothing.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Any errors in your browser's console? Please share the same.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The I want to make a dropdown which has a nested li inside and when u click it to display the nested li tags and then if u click again to hide it. There are no errors at the console by the way

Comment: Well then you’ll have to show us an actual example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using this stack overflow [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

The correct code for showing and hiding the nested uls is

news.onclick = function(){

var news = document.getElementById("news-ul");

function compareDisplayValue(){

var element = document.getElementById("news-ul");

var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);

var display = style.getPropertyValue('display');

if(display == "none"){

```
 news.style.display = "list-item";
```

}

else if (display == "list-item"){

```
 news.style.display = "none";
```

}

}

compareDisplayValue();

}

Answer (score 2):

I assume the outer `news` is a button that has already been assigned to a variable (or the default global via its ID).

The issue is if the element itself does not have a `display` set in its `style` attribute, then its initial value will be `""` instead of whatever was given in CSS.

Therefore instead of comparing to `"none"`, compare to `""`.

```js
news.onclick = function() {
  var news = document.getElementById("news-ul");
  if (news.style.display == "") {
    news.style.display = "list-item";
  } else {
    news.style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#news-ul {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button id=news>CLICK FOR NEWS</button>

<ul id="news-ul">
  <li>TEST
</ul>
```