# Getting bootstrap background color of a style

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to read the background color set by bootstrap in the alert box.

```
var qc = $(".alert-primary").css("background-color");
```

This returns undefined. How should I get its value?

Comment: probably a dupe, here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Comment: Working as expected for me. You sure some other code isn't interfering or you're trying to target a class that is loaded outside the DOM without a listener?  See: https://www.bootply.com/36vcaTAgHE

Comment: Working for me, may be you are not including jQuery or using this code before jQuery loads..

Comment: make sure there are any element with `alert-primary` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the selection works only *after* I 've created a DOM element with that class.

This works:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">hello</div>
<script>
   var aa = $(".alert-info").css("background-color");
   alert(aa);
</script>
```

Without the first line, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it perfectly right you can also do as follows:-

```
$(".alert-primary")[0].style.backgroundColor
```

or

```
var qc = $(".alert-primary").css("background-color");
```

I think your not getting $(".alert-primary") object. Please make sure $(".alert-primary") is getting the correct element, which has background-color.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined", but bootstrap is there. Let me try it in a ready().

Comment: That means you don't have element with .alert-primary class in DOM.

Comment: But I am able to use alert-primary in a div ... weird.