# getElementById().style.display does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made some js code for `<div>` to appear or disappear.

[src.js]

```
openSearch = () => {
    var con = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    if(con.style.display == 'none') {
        con.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        con.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

[style.css]

```
#search-bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

and add `onclick="openSearch()"` to `<a>` tag.

When I click the `<a>` tag first time, it doesn't work anything.

But click again, it works properly.

So I tried to console.log(document.getElementById("search-bar").style.display, it throws ""(blank).

I wonder that I defined `display: none` to `search-bar` but why initial style.display of `search-bar` is blank value?

And how can I fix it?

Comment: you forgot to add the html part, but my guess is that there is no style `display:none` on that div. When you check for `con.style.display` it is empty the first time. `div.style` is not the computed style, but the value of the attribute `style` on the div.

Comment: The `.style` property only contains styles set directly on the element. To include those applied by a stylesheet, [you can use `getComputedStyle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for comment. I will investigate it more.

Comment: You can do that pure CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can move the display style to another class and can toggle class.

```js
openSearch = () => {
    var con = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    con.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
#search-bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    right: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <a onclick="openSearch()">Toggle</a>
    <div id="search-bar" class="hidden">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: I solved issue for add style attribute directly to a tag, but thanks for reply!

Comment: @Hide - Good to hear that, however, i would suggest to avoid inline styles as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
function openSearch()
 {
       var div = document.getElementById("search-bar");
       if (div.style.display !== "none") {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      else {
         div.style.display = "block";
       }
 }
```

Comment: while the answer is correct, it does not explain what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

First I add `display: none` to css file.

But after `style="display: none"` to a tag, it works properly.

Maybe I think there is loading priority, But I don't know why exactly.

Comment: When you add the style attribute to the element, it takes higher precedence to the style defined in your stylesheet. Hence, it overrides the display style.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal I got it. So, My payload is a normal solution?

Comment: Yes it is. However, as mentioned in a comment on another answer, try to avoid inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try initializing the style via js to none:

```
document.getElementById("search-bar").style.display = 'none';
```

When the page loads. My guess is that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

when you set the `display:none` in css it innisial like `display=""`. and not `display=none`. the result is the same, but if you check `display='none'` he will return false.. you can try it like this:

```
openSearch = () => {
    var con = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    if(con.style.display == '') {
        con.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        con.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use this line code:

```
if(con.style.display == 'none' || con.style.display == '') {
```

```js
openSearch = () => {
    var con = document.getElementById("search-bar");
    if(con.style.display == 'none' || con.style.display == '') {
        con.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        con.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#search-bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4em;
  width: 20em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-bar">My Div</div>
<a onclick="openSearch()" href="#">Click</a>
```