# Onclick function not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I have created a side popup in my website, but I have an issue. It works fine, but only on the second click. I want it to work on the first click. When I click on it two times, it works. I already tried some other blogs tricks but it's not working.

What's going wrong?

I created it using simple JS, you can see my code below:

```js
function openNav() {
  navMenuStatus = document.getElementById('popup').style.right;
  if (navMenuStatus == '-300px') {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.right = '0px';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.right = '-300px';
  }
}
```

```css
.pmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.pmenu img {
  padding: 5px 11px;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.pmenu p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  background-color: #356381;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pbody {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #356381;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff000;
}

.pbody p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pbody h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff000;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.pbody h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #193e56;
  padding: 15px;
}

.address {
  text-align: center;
}

.address h6 {
  color: #356381;
  background-color: #fff000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-width: 245px;
  text-align: left;
}

.aicon {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #193e56;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 12px;
}

.aadd {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup">
  <div class="pmenu" onclick="openNav()">
    <p>GET THE<br/>BOOK</p>
    <img src="del.png">
  </div>
  <div class="pbody">
    <h4>HOW TO GET THE PHONEBOOK</h4>
    <p>Books were delivered to every house in Lakewood and surrounding areas during the month of February. </p>
    <h5>If you did not receive one after this time you may pick one up at either one of the Wine on 9 locations.</h5>
    <div class="address">
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>North location</b><br/> 6545 Rt 9 North, Howell, NJ 07731</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>South location</b><br/> 945 River Ave, Lakewood, NJ 08701</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Balvant_Ahir/pen/YjWNaN)

Comment: Please don't just post a link to you codepen, which is broken by the way. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: document.getElementById('popup').style.right returns "" the first time becaue the right attribute in the style hasnt been assigned. .style.right checks the style attribute, not the css

Comment: U shud have searched first, See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code checks for a `style` attribute of `right:-300px`. Since there is no `style` attribute on `#popup` on load, the first click only sets a style attribute of `right:-300px`. Then, the second click sets it to "0", etc.

Note that [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) references the element's *inline style* and does not reference CSS applied by `class`.

I had some success by setting a default `style` attribute of `-300px`.

```js
function openNav() {
  navMenuStatus = document.getElementById('popup').style.right;
  if (navMenuStatus == '-300px') {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.right = '0px';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.right = '-300px';
  }
}
```

```css
.pmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.pmenu img {
  padding: 5px 11px;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.pmenu p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  background-color: #356381;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pbody {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #356381;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff000;
}

.pbody p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pbody h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff000;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.pbody h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #193e56;
  padding: 15px;
}

.address {
  text-align: center;
}

.address h6 {
  color: #356381;
  background-color: #fff000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-width: 245px;
  text-align: left;
}

.aicon {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #193e56;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 12px;
}

.aadd {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup" style="right:-300px">
  <div class="pmenu" onclick="openNav()">
    <p>GET THE<br/>BOOK</p>
    <img src="del.png">
  </div>
  <div class="pbody">
    <h4>HOW TO GET THE PHONEBOOK</h4>
    <p>Books were delivered to every house in Lakewood and surrounding areas during the month of February. </p>
    <h5>If you did not receive one after this time you may pick one up at either one of the Wine on 9 locations.</h5>
    <div class="address">
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>North location</b><br/> 6545 Rt 9 North, Howell, NJ 07731</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>South location</b><br/> 945 River Ave, Lakewood, NJ 08701</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to find the `right` property set in your stylesheet.

```js
function openNav() {
  navMenuStatus = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('popup'), null).getPropertyValue('right');
  if (navMenuStatus == '-300px') {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.right = '0px';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.right = '-300px';
  }
}
```

```css
.pmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.pmenu img {
  padding: 5px 11px;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.pmenu p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  background-color: #356381;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pbody {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #356381;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff000;
}

.pbody p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pbody h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff000;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.pbody h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #193e56;
  padding: 15px;
}

.address {
  text-align: center;
}

.address h6 {
  color: #356381;
  background-color: #fff000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-width: 245px;
  text-align: left;
}

.aicon {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #193e56;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 12px;
}

.aadd {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup">
  <div class="pmenu" onclick="openNav()">
    <p>GET THE<br/>BOOK</p>
    <img src="del.png">
  </div>
  <div class="pbody">
    <h4>HOW TO GET THE PHONEBOOK</h4>
    <p>Books were delivered to every house in Lakewood and surrounding areas during the month of February. </p>
    <h5>If you did not receive one after this time you may pick one up at either one of the Wine on 9 locations.</h5>
    <div class="address">
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>North location</b><br/> 6545 Rt 9 North, Howell, NJ 07731</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>South location</b><br/> 945 River Ave, Lakewood, NJ 08701</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Perhaps better yet, use [`toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to toggle the element's CSS class in [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), as recommended by Arash Kazemi.

```js
var trigger = document.getElementById('popup_trigger');
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

function openNav() {
  popup.classList.toggle('hide');
}

trigger.addEventListener('click', openNav);
```

```css
.pmenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.pmenu img {
  padding: 5px 11px;
  background-color: #fff000;
}

.pmenu p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  background-color: #356381;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pbody {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #356381;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff000;
}

.pbody p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pbody h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff000;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.pbody h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #193e56;
  padding: 15px;
}

.address {
  text-align: center;
}

.address h6 {
  color: #356381;
  background-color: #fff000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-width: 245px;
  text-align: left;
}

.aicon {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #193e56;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 12px;
}

.aadd {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.popup.hide {
  right: -300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup hide" id="popup">
  <div class="pmenu" id="popup_trigger">
    <p>GET THE<br/>BOOK</p>
    <img src="del.png">
  </div>
  <div class="pbody">
    <h4>HOW TO GET THE PHONEBOOK</h4>
    <p>Books were delivered to every house in Lakewood and surrounding areas during the month of February. </p>
    <h5>If you did not receive one after this time you may pick one up at either one of the Wine on 9 locations.</h5>
    <div class="address">
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>North location</b><br/> 6545 Rt 9 North, Howell, NJ 07731</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="aicon">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="aadd">
        <h6><b>South location</b><br/> 945 River Ave, Lakewood, NJ 08701</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `document.getElementById('popup').style.right` is empty the first time you read it. The rule is not set for the element with id popup, instead it is set for the element with class popup.

A dirty quick solution would be checking for its equality with "0px". But a better way would be defining a class name `.opened-popup` with right equal to 0px. Then toggle that class on click. Like this:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('popup').classList.toggle("opened-popup");
}
```

Look at this for a good solution:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpyWQm