# Toggle element with cssText

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to toggle element visibility. Currently, when clicking button1, it's just hiding, and not toggling.

This is my code and I want to know why it doesn't show button2 after hiding it.

```js
function fonk10() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("eben")[0];
    if (x.style.cssText === "display:none") {
        x.style.cssText = "display:inline-block";
    } else {
        x.style.cssText = "display:none";
    }
}
```

```css
.eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="eben" onclick="fonk10()">BUTTON1</div>
<div class="eben">BUTTON2</div>
```

Comment: Hint: add `console.log(x.style.cssText)` before the `if` and make sure it matches *exactly* what you have after the `===`.

Comment: because there is a space and `;` : `display: none;` and honestly this is the wort way to read CSS

Comment: i'm newbie javascript user so i don't know what to do, can u give me prepared code?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript

Comment: unfortunately it's not related to the question.

Comment: it's 100% related to the question. The duplicate question will show you the exact way to read CSS property and use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you are using is always `false`. That's why always `else` is executing. You have to format the string little bit by inserting space after `:` and `;` at last.

Change

```
if (x.style.cssText === "display:none") {
```

To

```
if (x.style.cssText === "display: none;") {
```

```js
function fonk10() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("eben")[0];
  if (x.style.cssText === "display: none;") {
      x.style.cssText = "display: inline-block";
  } else {
      x.style.cssText = "display: none";
  }
}
```

```css
.eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="eben" onclick="fonk10()">BUTTON1</div>
<div class="eben">BUTTON2</div>
```

You can also use `display` property like the following way:

```js
function fonk10() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("eben")[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="eben" onclick="fonk10()">BUTTON1</div>
<div class="eben">BUTTON2</div>
```

Comment: i know this way but i use multiple css property.

Comment: thank you so much. codes are exactly what i want and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice question: you need inline stiles for the second button. You also need "orthographic precision" for your css roules. But I wouldn't recommend doing it in production.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("eben")[0];
function fonk10() {console.log(x.style.cssText)

    if (x.style.cssText === "display: inline-block;") {
        x.style.cssText = "display: none;"
    } else {
        x.style.cssText = "display: inline-block;";
    }
}
```

```css
.eben,#eben{
  background:green;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="eben" onclick="fonk10()">BUTTON1</div>
<div class="eben"  style="display: inline-block;">BUTTON2</div>
```

Comment: if you keep the initial if else we don't need inline style because we will fall into the else and starting from there we will have inline styles

Comment: thanks lot! it's working. i try and i found that i don't need inline style and console log, very thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Boolean variable explain your element status let us call it show , according to the element if it is displayed then show will be true else if hidden and make the validation with this variable

```
var show=true;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("eben")[0];
 function fonk10() {
if (show===false) {
    x.style.cssText = "display:inline-block";
show=true;
    } else {
        x.style.cssText = "display:none";
        show=false;
     }
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.