# How can I set a CSS keyframes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, keyframe

I have a CSS keyframes shown as below, my problem is I would like to set it as JavaScript (to put inside my div which already have some functions) so that I can return the "element" value to my function

```css
.cylon-eye {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75%);
  color: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move-eye;
}
@keyframes move-eye {
  from {
    margin-left: -20%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
```

I've tried to convert as below after suggestion, is that the return value i should call is `var cylon-eye = document.getElementById("cylon-eye");`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appendStyle(styles) {
var css = document.createElement('style');
css.type = 'text/css';

if (css.styleSheet) css.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
else css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);

}

var styles = '#cylon-eye { background-color: yellow; background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255, 0.9) 25%,rgba(255,255,255, 0.1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255, 0.9) 75%); color: none; height: 100%; width: 20%;animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move-eye; z-index: 10;}';
var keyFrames = '\
@keyframes move-eye {\
  from {\
    margin-left: -20%;\
  }\

  to {\
    margin-left: 100%;\
  }\
}';

window.onload = function() { appendStyle(styles) };
</script>
```

Comment: @lvy Hoo Hui En , I have shared example with two option in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575227/5783700 post, You can check that post, Hope it helps to you.

Comment: hi @ankitkanojia, thanks for the suggestion and coding. if i want to return the colors to a boxes that i create, i only need to "return element;" right?

Comment: @lvy Hoo Hui En, yes you can return but you need to provide an id to your dynamically created element on DOM in your example. or else you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338234/5783700 post better understanding, let me know still required anything. Thank you!!

Answer (score 13):

## 2022 SOLUTION

Now it's possible to use the method .animate() as in this example

```
document.getElementById("tunnel").animate([
  // key frames
  { transform: 'translateY(0px)' },
  { transform: 'translateY(-300px)' }
], {
  // sync options
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats (blink effect example)

Comment: How can I set `@keyframes scroll` using this?

Answer (score 8):

let me share with you two snippets, one is using **CSS + javascript** and another is only using **javascript**, you can use whatever preferred to you. Hope its helpful to you.

> WITH JAVASCRIPT

```js
let dynamicStyles = null;

function addAnimation(body) {
  if (!dynamicStyles) {
    dynamicStyles = document.createElement('style');
    dynamicStyles.type = 'text/css';
    document.head.appendChild(dynamicStyles);
  }

  dynamicStyles.sheet.insertRule(body, dynamicStyles.length);
}

addAnimation(`
      @keyframes move-eye { 
         from {
           margin-left: -20%;
         }
        to {
          margin-left: 100%;
        }
      }
    `);



var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "cylon-eye";
element.style.height = "50px";
element.style.width = "50px";
element.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 25%,rgba(255, 0, 0) 50%,rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 75%)";
element.style.animation = "4s linear 0s infinite alternate move-eye";

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

> WITH CSS + JAVASCRIPT

```js
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "cylon-eye";
element.style.height = "50px";
element.style.width = "50px";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

```css
.cylon-eye {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) 25%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9) 75%);
  color: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate move-eye;
}

@keyframes move-eye {
  from {
    margin-left: -20%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: The former doesn't work on Cromium, in my case. The latter does not really add (or modify, as I needed) the `keyframes`.

Answer (score 3):

this works fine for me, Hope this will help :)

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
var keyFrames = '\
@keyframes slidein {\
  from {\
    margin-left: 100%;\
    width: 300%; \
  }\

  to {\
    margin-left: 0%;\
    width: 100%;\
  }\
}';

document.getElementsById('slideDiv')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Please use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: And keyFrames can be a `const` as it's never changed

Comment: Don't you think the `keyFrames` should be related to the `style`, somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It would be wise to use Native API functionality to alter `CSSStyleSheets`. You can access existing stylesheets using the following method

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
```

This will return all applied rules and you will be able to edit the rule where the `selectorText` matches your `selector`

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using a `<style></style>` tag?

For example:

```js
const loading = document.querySelector('.loading');
const keyFrames = document.createElement("style");

keyFrames.innerHTML = `
  @keyframes loading {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  .loading {
    animation: loading 1s ease infinite;
  }
`;

loading.appendChild(keyFrames);
```

```css
.loading {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.24ways.org%2F2009%2F15%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Fspinner.png&f=1&nofb=1');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Keyframes in js</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loading"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.head.appendChild(keyFrames);` is more reasonable, I think.

Comment: This worked on Firefox and Cromium, for me and when modifying `keyFrames` multiple times (`onResize`).

Answer (score 0):

This is good for me.

```
document.getElementById(nodeID).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
`
<style type="text/css">
  @keyframes your-animation {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }
</style>
`
)
```