# How to access properties of id styles in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kind of new to Web Development and I was trying to access a property of and id.style in my site, but unfortunately there was no response in my program so I have uploaded my problem in this code.
please also tell me how to change that value.

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("container");
  alert(elem.style.top);

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: why are you printing `top` ? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Your code is working as expected, `#container` element doesn't have `top` setted in its inline html, so it returns nothing. Maybe you are looking for `computedStyle`?

Comment: I was just trying to access top and left properties to create something similar to animation.

Comment: `.style` only contains inline styles, not styles that are inherited from CSS.

Comment: based on your edit, see @Barmar comment and also take a look about `window.getComputedStyle`

Comment: sorry I have edited the code there was no top in id.styles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access the CSS value you want using `window.getComputedStyle()`

See [MDN for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

But what you may really want is `element.offsetTop;`

See [MDN here for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

```
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("container");
  var computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
  var top = computedStyles.getPropertyValue('top')
  alert(top);
  alert(elem.offsetTop);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I also want to change that value, than in that case what should I do?

Comment: Programmatically, you can only change `elem.style.top`, and you do so like this: `elem.style.top = '20px' // (or any valid CSS value)`. But that might not do what you expect. I suggest you post another question with a clearer goal.