# My display style.display test fail when using == or === but suceed when using only =

Tags: javascript, css

There is something I can't understand. I have a basic function with 2 buttons, when clicking the first it should hide the other one & reveal it if it was previously hidden.

I use a style.display test but unless I use only "=" in my test, it fails. I don't get why. Any hint please?

Here is the code with a "mistake" that works:

```js
function reduce() { 
if (document.getElementById("B5").style.display = "block")
{
document.getElementById("B5").style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```html
<button id="B1" onclick="reduce()">Button 1</button>
<button id="B5" >Button 2 (to hide)</button>
```

Here is the one that should work but does not:

```js
function reduce() { 
if (document.getElementById("B5").style.display == "block")
{
document.getElementById("B5").style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```html
<button id="B1" onclick="reduce()">Button 1</button>
<button id="B5" >Button 2 (to hide)</button>
```

Where do I get it wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `=` is assignment. You assign the right hand value to the left hand property. `==` is value comparison, `===` is value & type comparison. For eg `1 == '1'` will return true whereas `1 === '1'` will return false

Comment: The first one "works" basically because the if condition is always true. See [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Comment: Ok thanks, and can you tell what's wrong with second piece of code? Why does style.display == "block" fail?

Comment: See the link in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can not get the style by `xxx.style` of an element if the style is not defined inline, so `document.getElementById("B5").style.display` is always going to be `""` by default.

> Solution: use [`window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("B5"))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead

2. The default `display` of `button` is `inline-block`, not `block`. So `display === "block"` will never work.

> Solution: use `display !== "none"` instead

Here's an example of how it should be done:

```js
function reduce() { 
  if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("B5")).display !== "none") {
    document.getElementById("B5").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // restore the style of B5 to its original state
    document.getElementById("B5").style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="B1" onclick="reduce()">Button 1</button>
<button id="B5" >Button 2 (to hide)</button>
```

Comment: great thanks !
I lacked the difference between inline style and computed style. Now I understand,
Nice of you to help have a good day

Answer (score 2):

`=` is assignment. You assign the right hand value to the left hand property. == is value comparison, `===` is value & type comparison. For eg `1 == '1'` will return true whereas `1 === '1'` will return false

In your first snippet you assign `block` to the button's display property. That is not a comparison so it will return true ( but it's wrong )

That being said, the button element doesn't have `display:block` set by default. It has `display: inline-block`. But that is a computed style ( attributed by the browser )

I suggest using a `!= 'none'` comparison in the second snippet. Or get the computed style and compare it to `inline-block` or `block`

See below

```js
function reduce() { 

const buttonB5 = document.getElementById("B5")
const buttonB5Display = window.getComputedStyle(buttonB5, null).getPropertyValue('display') // use this to get computed display style

if (buttonB5.style.display != 'none')
// or if (buttonB5Display == "inline-block" || buttonB5Display == 'block')
  {
    buttonB5.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<button id="B1" onclick="reduce()">Button 1</button>
<button id="B5" >Button 2 (to hide)</button>
```

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot for your help !