# Get the css definition of an element

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a fast way to retrieve the CSS `width` definition (or any other CSS attribute) of an element?

Notes

1. I need to know the actual definition, like `80%` or `42vw`, and NOT the calculated pixel dimension.
2. The width might be set on different CSS selectors, as illustrated in the code below

Here is a sample of the markup/CSS I have:

```css
body div > section { 
    width: 30% 
}
#content section { 
    width: auto 
}
first { 
    width: 75% !important
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <section class="first"> ... </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Problem: I want to find out via JS, that the `<section>` has a width of `75%`.

Unfortunately, `getMatchedCSSRules()` is exactly what I need, but it's deprecated and already removed from browsers.

Comment: Does `element.style.width` work?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6338217/13833218

Comment: @evolutionxbox - that will deliver the expected result, but I'm looking for a way to get the definition from a CSS rule (not of the elements inline style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to determine the exact CSS definition of any element by inspecting the [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList) collection.

Getting accurate results was quite complex, as the result needs to respect (a) media queries that [match the current viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) and (b) evaluate the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of selectors.

Here is a complete function that's optimized for high performance - finding a single property among 40+ CSS files with a total of 15k+ of individual rules took 40-50ms

[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/stracker-phil/4ba0b9b9ad67dff268c9130f2fdbb473) (might be more current than the code below)

```js
/**
 * Scans all CSS rules in the current document to find the most
 * specific definiton of a single CSS property for a given element.
 *
 * Usage: getStyleDef('#my-element', 'width'); 
 *  --> returns the most specific "width" defintiion, e.g. "27em".
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} element - The HTML Element to inspect.
 * @param {string} prop - The CSS property to inspect.
 * @return {string} The most specific CSS definition, 
 *         or an empty string.
 */
function getStyleDef(element, prop) {
    let result = '';
    let highestSpecificity = false;
    const allRules = [];
    const relevantRules = [];

    // Translate a selector string into an HTMLElement.
    if ('string' === typeof element) {
        element = document.querySelector(element);
    }

    // Translate a jQuery element to a HTMLElement.
    if (element && element instanceof jQuery) {
        element = element.get(0);
    }

    // Bail, if no valid element is specified.
    if (!element || !(element instanceof HTMLElement)) {
        return '';
    }

    // When an inline style is set, always return it.
    if (element.style && '' !== element.style[prop]) {
        return element.style[prop];
    }

    // Parse all stylesheet entries to find relevant CSS rules.
    _getRelevantRules(element);

    // Loop all relevant rules to find the most specific one.
    for (let i = relevantRules.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Is there a rule for the required property?
        if ('' === relevantRules[i].style[prop]) {
            continue;
        }

        // Determine the specificity of the given CSS selector.
        const specificity = _getCssSpecificity(
            relevantRules[i].selectorText,
            relevantRules[i].style[prop]
        );

        // Find the most specific CSS definition.
        if (_compareCssSpecificity(specificity, highestSpecificity) > 0) {
            highestSpecificity = specificity;
            result = relevantRules[i].style[prop];
        }
    }

    return result;

    // -- Helper functions follow --

    /**
     * Convert an array-like object to array.
     *
     * @param {Iterable} list - A value-list that can be converted to an array.
     * @return {array} An array representation of the list, or an empty array.
     */
    function _toArray(list) {
        if ('undefined' === typeof list || null === list) {
            return [];
        }
        try {
            if ('function' === typeof Array.from) {
                return Array.from(list);
            } else {
                return [].slice.call(list);
            }
        } catch (exception) {
            // In case the list cannot be converted, return an empty array.
            return [];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles extraction of `cssRules` as an `Array` from a stylesheet
     * or something that behaves the same.
     *
     * The rules are prepended to the allRules array. This function does
     * not return a value.
     *
     * @param {CSSStyleSheet} stylesheet - The stylesheet to parse.
     */
    function _extractSheetRules(stylesheet) {
        try {
            // Skip disabled rules.
            if (stylesheet.disabled) {
                return;
            }

            // Skip rules that do not match the current viewport.
            const media = stylesheet.media;
            if (media && !matchMedia(media.mediaText).matches) {
                return;
            }

            // Prepend the rules to the `allRules` array.
            Array.prototype.unshift.apply(allRules, _toArray(stylesheet.cssRules));
        } catch (exception) {
            /*
             * CORS prevents us from accessing rules from other domains, such
             * as google font styles.
             */
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses all stylesheets and populates the `relevantRules` array with CSS
     * rules that match the given element AND the current viewport size.
     *
     * @param {HTMLElement} element - The element to inspect.
     * @private
     */
    function _getRelevantRules(element) {
        let rule;

        // assuming the browser hands us stylesheets in order of appearance
        // we iterate them from the beginning to follow proper cascade order
        for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {

            // Extract the style rules of this sheet into `allRules`.
            _extractSheetRules(document.styleSheets[i]);

            // Loop the rules in order of appearance.
            while (rule = allRules.shift()) {
                if (rule.styleSheet) {
                    // Insert the `@import`ed stylesheet's rules at the
                    // beginning of this stylesheet's rules.
                    _extractSheetRules(rule.styleSheet);

                    // ... and skip the rest of this rule.
                    continue;
                }

                // If there's no stylesheet attribute BUT there IS a
                // media attribute it's a media rule.
                if (rule.media) {
                    // insert the contained rules of this media rule to
                    // the beginning of this stylesheet's rules.
                    _extractSheetRules(rule);

                    // ... and skip the rest it.
                    continue;
                }

                // check if this element matches this rule's selector
                if (element.matches(rule.selectorText)) {
                    // push the rule to the results set
                    relevantRules.push(rule);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Calculates the CSS specificity of a CSS selector.
     *
     *  @param input - The CSS selector.
     *  @param attribValue - Optional. A specific CSS attribute value. Only used
     *         to properly recognize `!important` values.
     *  @return {array} Always an array with 4 elements.
     */
    function _getCssSpecificity(input, attribValue) {
        const token = input.split(',');

        if (token.length > 1) {
            let result = [];
            let singleSpecificity;

            for (let i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
                singleSpecificity = _getCssSpecificity(token[i]);
                if (_compareCssSpecificity(singleSpecificity, result) > 0) {
                    result = singleSpecificity;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        let selector = input,
            findMatch,
            typeCount = {
                'a': 0,
                'b': 0,
                'c': 0
            },
            // The following regular expressions assume that selectors matching the
            // preceding regular expressions have been removed.
            attributeRegex = /(\[[^\]]+\])/g,
            idRegex = /(#[^\#\s\+>~\.\[:\)]+)/g,
            classRegex = /(\.[^\s\+>~\.\[:\)]+)/g,
            pseudoElementRegex = /(::[^\s\+>~\.\[:]+|:first-line|:first-letter|:before|:after)/gi,
            // A regex for pseudo classes with brackets - :nth-child(),
            // :nth-last-child(), :nth-of-type(), :nth-last-type(), :lang()
            // The negation pseudo class (:not) is filtered out because specificity
            // is calculated on its argument.
            // :global and :local are filtered out - they look like pseudo classes
            // but are an identifier for CSS Modules.
            pseudoClassWithBracketsRegex = /(:(?!not|global|local)[\w-]+\([^\)]*\))/gi,
            // A regex for other pseudo classes, which don't have brackets
            pseudoClassRegex = /(:(?!not|global|local)[^\s\+>~\.\[:]+)/g,
            elementRegex = /([^\s\+>~\.\[:]+)/g,
            isImportant;

        isImportant = 'string' === typeof attribValue && attribValue.indexOf('!important') > 0;

        // Find matches for a regular expression in a string and push their details
        // to parts. Type is "a" for IDs, "b" for classes, attributes and pseudo-
        // classes and "c" for elements and pseudo-elements.
        findMatch = function (regex, type) {
            let matches, i, len, match, index, length;
            if (regex.test(selector)) {
                matches = selector.match(regex);
                for (i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                    typeCount[type] += 1;
                    match = matches[i];
                    index = selector.indexOf(match);
                    length = match.length;
                    // Replace this simple selector with whitespace so it won't be
                    // counted in further simple selectors.
                    selector = selector.replace(match, Array(length + 1).join(' '));
                }
            }
        };

        // Replace escaped characters with plain text, using the "A" character
        // https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters
        (function () {
            const replaceWithPlainText = function (regex) {
                    let matches, i, len, match;

                    if (regex.test(selector)) {
                        matches = selector.match(regex);
                        for (i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                            match = matches[i];
                            selector = selector.replace(match, Array(match.length + 1).join('A'));
                        }
                    }
                },
                // Matches a backslash followed by six hexadecimal digits followed
                // by an optional single whitespace character.
                escapeHexadecimalRegex = /\\[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\s?/g,
                // Matches a backslash followed by fewer than six hexadecimal digits
                // followed by a mandatory single whitespace character.
                escapeHexadecimalRegex2 = /\\[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,5}\s/g,
                // Matches a backslash followed by any character.
                escapeSpecialCharacter = /\\./g;

            replaceWithPlainText(escapeHexadecimalRegex);
            replaceWithPlainText(escapeHexadecimalRegex2);
            replaceWithPlainText(escapeSpecialCharacter);
        }());

        // Remove anything after a left brace in case a user has pasted in a rule, not just a
        // selector
        (function () {
            let regex = /{[^]*/gm,
                matches, i, len, match;

            if (regex.test(selector)) {
                matches = selector.match(regex);
                for (i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                    match = matches[i];
                    selector = selector.replace(match, Array(match.length + 1).join(' '));
                }
            }
        }());

        // Add attribute selectors to parts collection (type b)
        findMatch(attributeRegex, 'b');

        // Add ID selectors to parts collection (type a)
        findMatch(idRegex, 'a');

        // Add class selectors to parts collection (type b)
        findMatch(classRegex, 'b');

        // Add pseudo-element selectors to parts collection (type c)
        findMatch(pseudoElementRegex, 'c');

        // Add pseudo-class selectors to parts collection (type b)
        findMatch(pseudoClassWithBracketsRegex, 'b');
        findMatch(pseudoClassRegex, 'b');

        // Remove universal selector and separator characters
        selector = selector.replace(/[\*\s\+>~]/g, ' ');

        // Remove any stray dots or hashes which aren't attached to words
        // These may be present if the user is live-editing this selector
        selector = selector.replace(/[#\.]/g, ' ');

        // Remove the negation pseudo-class (:not) but leave its argument because
        // specificity is calculated on its argument. Remove non-standard :local and
        // :global CSS Module identifiers because they do not effect the specificity.
        selector = selector.replace(/:not/g, '    ');
        selector = selector.replace(/:local/g, '      ');
        selector = selector.replace(/:global/g, '       ');
        selector = selector.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ' ');

        // The only things left should be element selectors (type c)
        findMatch(elementRegex, 'c');

        return [isImportant ? 1 : 0, typeCount.a, typeCount.b, typeCount.c];
    }

    /**
     * Compares two CSS Specificity terms to determine, which one is more
     * specific.
     *
     * @param a - The first term
     * @param b - The second term.
     * @returns {number} 0 if both are equally specific. +1 if a is more
     *          specific, -1 if b is more specific.
     */
    function _compareCssSpecificity(a, b) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
            const valA = parseInt(isNaN(a[i]) ? 0 : a[i]);
            const valB = parseInt(isNaN(b[i]) ? 0 : b[i]);

            if (valA < valB) {
                return -1;
            } else if (valA > valB) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. You need to convert the with in percentage.

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
  var f = $("section").width() / $("section").parent().width() * 100;
  
  console.log(f+"%");
});
```

```css
body div > section { 
    width: 30%;
}
#content section { 
    width: auto; 
}
.first { 
    width: 75% !important;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <section class="first"> ... </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to convert the current width to a percentage, but to determine the actual defined value. like `auto`, `75%`, `30em`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The only way is Inspect Element

Comment: Do you want to say, it's not possible to get the definition via JS?

Comment: @Philipp You may do that with some tools but that is not possible with plain JS.good luck