# How to get transform value with jq?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem to get element with jQuery. This is my html, css and jQuery code. Please check it and tell me, how can I get transform value with jQuery?

I need get transform value with jQuery, but I can't; can you help me?

```
<script>
    var movment = 150;
    var time=1000;

    $('.btn_left').click(function () {

        $('.slider').css({
            'transform': 'translateX(' + movment + 'px)',
            'transition':time+'ms'
        });

        movment = movment + 150;
    })
    $('.btn_right').click(function () {

        // var getElementtransform=??;

        movment = movment - 150;
        $('.slider').css({
            'transform': 'translateX(' + movment + 'px)',
            'transition':time+'ms'
        });
    })
</script>


<style>
    .slider {
        width: 2200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .btn_right {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .btn_left {
        float: left;
        transform: scale(1.3);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .items {
        width: 150px;
        height: 180px;
        margin: 10px 18px;
        background: green;
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: white;
        float: right;
        font-size: 46px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 156px;
        font-family: IRANSansWeb;
    }
</style>


<div class="slider">
    <div class="items">1</div>
    <div class="items">2</div>
    <div class="items">3</div>
    <div class="items">4</div>
    <div class="items">5</div>
    <div class="items">6</div>
    <div class="items">7</div>
    <div class="items">8</div>
    <div class="items">9</div>
    <div class="items">10</div>

</div>
<button class="btn_right">right</button>
<button class="btn_left">left</button>
```

Comment: var getElementtransform=$('.slider')[0].style.transform;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var getElementtransform=$('.slider')[0].style.transform;
```

or just the number:

```
var getElementtransform=Number($('.slider')[0].style.transform.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

Comment: excuse me, how can just get number value? f.e:  translateX(750px) ... i need just "750"(number) ... i have get number this value

Comment: @AliShojaei ```var getElementtransform=Number($('.slider')[0].style.transform.match(/\d+/)[0]);```

Comment: thanks, your guide help me;