# Getting element width as a percentage

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have an input elements whose width is set as a percentage in css. All these elements have a common class 'display-class'

Eg.

```
input.test1 {
   width: 60%
}
```

Now in JS, I am trying to set a wrapper div to this element. I want the wrapper div to have the width of input field and set the width of input field to 100%

My current JS code looks like this -

```
document.querySelectorAll('.display-class').forEach((el) => {
    const wrap = document.createElement('div');
    wrap.classList.add('display-class-wrap');
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, el);
    wrap.appendChild(el);
    wrap.style.width = el.style.width;
    el.style.width = '100%';
});
```

When I try to log the width's of both elements, it returns me empty string for length of input element.

I also tried setting the width by calculating the percentage myself like so,

```
wrap.style.width = `${(el.clientWidth/wrap.parentElement.clientWidth)*100}%`;
```

But it returns me width in float values that are way off the original width set. Eg. It returned 55.925% for 60%

Snippet:

```js
const initialHtml = initial.outerHTML;

function reset() {
  initial.outerHTML = initialHtml;
}

function wrapElements1() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.display-class').forEach((el) => {
      const wrap = document.createElement('div');
      wrap.classList.add('display-class-wrap');
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, el);
      wrap.appendChild(el);
      wrap.style.width = el.style.width;
      el.style.width = '100%';
  });
}

function wrapElements2() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.display-class').forEach((el) => {
      const wrap = document.createElement('div');
      wrap.classList.add('display-class-wrap');
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, el);
      wrap.appendChild(el);
      wrap.style.width = `${(el.clientWidth/wrap.parentElement.clientWidth)*100}%`;
      el.style.width = '100%';
  });
}
```

```html
<style>
input.test1 {
   width: 60%
}

.display-class {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.display-class-wrap {
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
</style>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="wrapElements1()">Wrap 1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="wrapElements2()">Wrap 2</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

  <div id="initial">
    <input class="display-class test1" name="input-1" type="text" />

    <input class="display-class test1" name="input-2" type="text" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer was marked as '[already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)', but this still doesnot solve my doubt. I need the exact percentage value set in css. `getComputedStyle()` returns me a value in px, from which even if I calculate the percentage myself, it's way off from the actual percentage

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.offsetWidth` directly on the element. `style` will not return the width until the width is explicitly set on the element.

But the gotcha around the `offsetWidth` is that it can return 0 if you do certain DOM modifications use `setTimeout` for those scenarios.

Another option for you is to use `getComputedStyle`. Checkout the documentation on how to use it.

If you can create a codeSandbox I can look into it as well :).
I hope this helps