# Why JavaScript didint see that id visibility is set to hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I whant that some element in my page appears only when a check box is selected, and disappears when it is not.

So I have this HTML:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" onchange="test('f1')"> Is selected?</td>
<div id="f1">some content</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function test(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility === "hidden") {
      document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
      document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

And CSS:

```
#f1 {visibility: hidden;}
```

Right now it is working but not perfect, because the first select is always hidden.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a style's value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-retrieve-a-styles-value-in-javascript) and many others

Comment: OK I understand now, that it is hard to do in that wy with css file :) can close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Juhana stated in the comments, the answer you're looking, which is explained perfectly in the link - is that: `.style.*` only looks at `inline` elements, quote:

> "The `element.style` property lets you know only the `CSS` properties that were defined as inline in that element (programmatically, or defined in the style attribute of the element), you should get the computed style."

If you tweak your function a little bit to check if `.style.visibility` hasn't been set yet (thus `''`), it'll toggle it upon first click.

```
function changeVisiblity() {
    if ( getContent.style.visibility == "hidden" || getContent.style.visibility == '' ) {
        getContent.style.visibility = "visible";  
    } else {
        getContent.style.visibility = "hidden";    
    }
}
```

Secondly, try to teach yourself to keep away from `onclick` within HTML elements, as this makes it much harder to maintain the future.

```
var getCheckbox = document.getElementById("testcheckbox"),
    getContent = document.getElementById("f1");

getCheckbox.addEventListener( 'change', changeVisiblity, null );
```

**[Demo Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/4yfWD/)** http://jsfiddle.net/4yfWD/