# Why aren't javascript and absolute positioning working together properly?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get the `onkeypress` function to manipulate absolute positioning. My code works once just fine, and then the element never moves again. 
Any help would be much appreciated.
 **JavaScript:**

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            div.style.left = (div.style.left - 10) + 'px';
        break;
    }
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<html><body><div id='div'></div></body></html>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gilbert_Virgo/N3KfW/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N3KfW/1/

Comment: The `style` property is not reliable as a getter. See the duplicate and [How to retrieve a style's value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2664045/464709)

Comment: @sahbeewah Put that as an answer and I'll give you the vote.