# Programatically positioning things inside a parent element by percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering what the **correct** way of programatically setting an elements position inside a parent element (as a percentage) from javascript would be.

In CSS you can do something like:

```
left: 25%;
```

There are two things I would like to avoid: jQuery, and calculating an absolute position based on the current size of the parent element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but to change a css property programmatically you can access it using the element's `style` property. An example:

```
<div id="thisdiv"><span id="thisspan">Hello</span></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('thisspan').style.marginLeft = "25%";
</script>
```

The css property `margin-left` becomes `marginLeft` in JavaScript. The percentage is measured with respect to the element's parent container-element, so doesn't need to be calculated.

Alternatively, define css-styles and change the element's `className`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add padding to the parent element:

```
parent = document.getelementById("id").parentNode;
parent.style.paddingLeft = "25%";
```

If you want to do it on the element itself is more difficult. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-retrieve-a-styles-value-in-javascript) for more details.

Comment: That link is about reading a css property-value, which is more complicated. Setting a value is straight-forward.

Comment: Adding padding to the parent element is a less favourable solution if there are multiple children

Comment: @Andy G Yes, that is what I am saying: "is more difficult"

Comment: @kvanberendonck The original question is quite vague. Eg, adding padding is better if there are floating elements where margin would not work.