# Javascript - element.style.left returning blank

Tags: javascript

My code here is designed to have a slide menu pull out. For some reason, I cannot seem to grab the "left" styling property of my element with id "news". Here is my javascript:

```
var current;
var currentValue;
var motionDir = 1;
window.onload = slide;
function slide() {
    current = document.getElementById('news'); //returns HTML Object div
    currentValue = current.style.left; //returns blank
    function move() {
        if(motionDir == 1) {
            if(currentValue !== '0%') {
                currentValue = parseInt(currentValue.substring(0, currentValue.length - 1)) + 2;
                current.style.left = currentValue + '%';
            } else {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        } else {
            if(currentValue !== '-50%') {
                currentValue = parseInt(currentValue.substring(0, currentValue.length - 1)) - 2;
                current.style.left = currentValue + '%';
            } else {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }
    }
    var intervalID = setInterval(move, 20);
}
```

Notice where I set the current andent currentValue variables. CurrentValue returns a blank value for whatever style property I try setting it to. If I do:

```
currentValue = current.style;
```

Then it outputs [OBbject CSS2Properties] and I am unsure why it does not say CSS3. Anyways, I am totally stumped and have spent an hour trying to debug this, but no luck. I can assure you that all the code runs fine and it is linked properly to the DOM.

Comment: Why would you expect it to have a `left` style set?

Comment: Because I gave it a left value in my stylesheet.

Comment: Your stylesheet is irrelevant. `.style` represents the element styles given in the `style` html attribute.

Comment: But I swear, I SWEAR I have used .style before on properties applied via the stylesheet rather than inline.

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense now! I am testing this on a laptop rather than on a web server, and when a web server runs it it appends all the stylesheet properties TO the HTML document. Makes sense why it won't work now!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to work unless you defined it as an *inline* style.

What that means is that you would have to have:

```
<div id="news" style="left: 15px;"></div>
```

in order for it to work.

You could use [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft) to get it in a similar fashion, otherwise look at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664055/293291).

Comment: Hmm, weird, because I have used top before and it was defined in the stylesheet.

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense now! I am testing this on a laptop rather than on a web server, and when a web server runs it it appends all the stylesheet properties TO the HTML document. Makes sense why it won't work now!!!