# is there any way using plaint JS to get value of a css property of an element?

Tags: javascript

As far as I concern, .style.some_property only returns the value of the property if I setting it in javascript. If I don't, it returns empty string. So, is there any other way other than jQuery methods like css() and prop() to get value of a css property?

Comment: CSS properties defined by style sheets and CSS properties applied by JavaScript are *very* different

Comment: so how jQuery can allow us to get css properties?

Comment: [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: By value of CSS property do you mean the actual styling like padding: 10px?

Comment: [How to retrieve a style's value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-retrieve-a-styles-value-in-javascript)

Comment: This is also explained in the [jQuery documentation about `.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/): *"The `.css()` method is a convenient way to get a style property from the first matched element, especially in light of the different ways browsers access most of those properties (the `getComputedStyle()` method in standards-based browsers versus the `currentStyle` and `runtimeStyle` properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms browsers use for certain properties"*

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) This will return all applied styles to an element