# Cannot get color of html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot get the colour of an html element using javascript until after it has been set in the script. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        h1 {
            color: purple;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var header = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
            alert("Colour: " + header.style.color); // Does not get the correct colour
            header.style.color = "yellow";
            alert("Colour: " + header.style.color); // Gets the correct colour
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the first alert to show "Colour: purple" as set in the css and the second to show "Colour: yellow" from the function itself. However, the first alert simply shows "Colour: ". In both cases, the colour of the element is correct and verified using firebug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style.property` gets only CSS properties assigned directly on the element.
To get the actual property value no matter where it was assigned (external stylesheet or inline) use `window.getComputedStyle(element).property`, where element is a reference to your element.

So in your example it would be:

```
alert("Colour: " + getComputedStyle(header).color);
```

See definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Thank you, this lead me in the correct direction. For anybody else finding this, there is a closing braket missing before the semi-colon.

Comment: Almost - this is what worked for me -  alert("Colour: " + window.getComputedStyle(header).color);

Answer (score 1):

For elements that are styled via CSS, to get their rendered style, you need to use [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```
alert(getComputedStyle(header).color) // the color you want
```