# How can I make a div appear onclick in js

Tags: javascript

I have a div element and I set its display to none in css. Then in my main.js file I wanted to change the display to block after I click on a button like so:

```js
    var btnClick = document.getElementById("my-btn");

    btnClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
 var myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");

 if (myDiv.style.display == "none") {
  myDiv.style.display = "block";
 }
    else {
   myDiv.style.display = "none";
  alert("here")
 }
    });
```

```css
#my-div {   
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>

<button id="my-btn">Click</button>
```

But when I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2664045/6303733

Answer (score 0):

It should be `myDiv.style.display` condition

```
var btnClick = document.getElementById("my-btn");

btnClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
    if (myDiv.style.display == "none") {
       myDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Comment: Explanation for the down vote - you cannot access the `style.display` if it was defined by css.

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with your code in `myDiv.display`, as there is no `display` property to your div (it's a property of `style`), however - even with the `style` you cannot have immediate access to the `display` property.

You cannot get the style definition from the css using `element.style.X`.
In order to do so you need to use `window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue`

Here is an example:

```js
var btnClick = document.getElementById("my-btn");
btnClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
  if (myDiv.style.display == "none" || window.getComputedStyle(myDiv, null).getPropertyValue("display") == "none") {
      myDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    myDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#my-div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
</div>

<button id="my-btn">Click</button>
```

There is a good reason for using external libraries (like jquery) for stuff like that :)