# Change display style property of a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a div onclick of a btn by changing the style property of the div. But I can't read the display property of that div. I read somewhere that the code doesn't work because the script tries to get the value before the div has loaded so the script should be triggered after window.onload. How do I make the script work after window has loaded but only when the button has been clicked ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
#hidden-div{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMe() {
   var foo = document.getElementById('hidden-div');
   alert(foo.style.display); //this gives a blank alert

   if(foo.style.display == ''){
    foo.style.display = 'block';
   }
   else {
    foo.style.display == 'none';
   } 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn-me" onclick="showMe()">+ clicking here should display the checkboxes</input><br>

  <div id="hidden-div">

  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1"> Check 1</input>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-2"> Check 2</input>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-3"> Check 3</input>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no`</input>` tag. Inputs are self-closing

Comment: You do understand that `==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment

Comment: </input> was included  by sublime. Didn't notice.

Comment: @AndrewL. Yes I do know that. Kindly explain how is that relevant here ?

Comment: You did `foo.style.display == 'none';`. You attempted to assign, but compared :)

Comment: @AndrewL. oh yes. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something to note: `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment. Also, there are no closing input tags. Here's the finished snippet:

```js
function showMe() {
   var foo = document.getElementById('hidden-div');

   if(foo.style.display == '' || foo.style.display == 'none'){
        foo.style.display = 'block';
   }
   else {
        foo.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn-me" onclick="showMe()">+ clicking here should display the checkboxes</input><br>

  <div id="hidden-div" style="display:none;">

  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1"> Check 1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-2"> Check 2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-3"> Check 3

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also changed some logic. If the `display` is none, and the button is clicked, toggle the visibility. If `display` is not none, then make it none.

The thing is `element.style.<style>` is only accessible if the style is set inline.

Comment: You could note that it'd also be better to get the element styles by using `getComputedStyle`, which returns the active styles in a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object.

Comment: Of course, but for demonstration purposes, `element.style.<style>` will be fine @nicematt

Comment: Thanks. Your code works. But if you notice I have set display = 'none' in the style tag. Can you please tell me why doesn't the script read from the internal style tag ?

Comment: @Etherealm It's not a tag, but a property. You were comparing the value of `HTMLElement().style.display`

Comment: The OP set the style via a style block and shouldn't need to inline the CSS.

Comment: @j08691 Just noticed that :)

Comment: @Etherealm The style attribute is only accessible if the styling is inline. You must set it inline or use `getComputedStyle`

Answer (score 1):

`foo.style.display` only works for styling that has been set inline, not for stylehseets or blocks. For that you would use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```js
function showMe() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("hidden-div");
  var foo = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
  if (foo.getPropertyValue("display") == 'none') {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn-me" onclick="showMe()">+ clicking here should display the checkboxes
<br>
<div id="hidden-div">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1"> Check 1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-2"> Check 2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-3"> Check 3
</div>
```

Comment: @nicematt Aside from the incorrect `==` actually it is.