# returning css property of an element in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In jQuery, the css property of an element, can be returned using methods. One example is the `width()` method that returns the width of an element, like this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert($(this).width());
});
```

However, in vanilla JS, I tried the following code, but it returned null:

```
document.querySelector('div').onclick = function() {
    alert(this.style.width);
}
```

How can I make it correct? I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: Did you try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the width.

Here is a snippet

```
document.querySelector('div').onclick = function() {
var width = window.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue("width");
    alert(width);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2fwgm8u/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea

Answer (score 0):

**this** here points to event object.you can it to the following

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    getWidth(event)
  });
}

function getWidth(event) {

  console.log(event.target.style.width);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px">
  hellow
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been asked earlier, [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2664045). The ans is as below, the answer also includes a sample code snippet to get css using JavaScript.

> The *element.style* property lets you know only the CSS properties that
>   were defined as *inline* in that element (programmatically, or defined
>   in the style attribute of the element), you should get the *computed
>   style*.