# Get the style property of an html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have applied a `font-size:` style to my `html` tag via stylesheet. I would like to retrieve it in javascript.

I have tried doing `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style` and I end up retrieving the styles with no values.

Comment: Is the [`window.getComputedStyle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) what you're looking for?

Comment: @nnnnnn I have tried applying it, but was unsuccessful

Comment: @nnnnnn just tried it again and it worked... Thank you. `let elem = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
   console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("font-size"))`

Comment: Hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.fontSize`?

Comment: @PhilS this didn't work, unsure why. I had to use `window.getComputedStyle`

Comment: Ok thanks, I hadn't tried it, just thought it might work, glad you got it working anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html` element can be referred by `document.documentElement` Try the following:

```js
var elem = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
var fontSize = elem.fontSize;
console.log(fontSize);
```

```css
html{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
let elem = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
```