# CSS Values Cannot be Pulled by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website project and I am puzzled about this fact. Once javascript runs it always returns false for any value. In order to simplify it, I wrote a simple code and put it in here so you can see what is going on.

I believe if I put the whole css and javascript codes in html file this issue wont recur.

https://jsfiddle.net/0m2L7f1u/

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="test">This is an example</p>
     <button type="button" id="myButton">Click</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#test{
    display: block;
    color: blue;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", toggleMe);

function toggleMe(){
    alert(document.getElementById("test").style.display == "block");
    alert(document.getElementById("test").style.color == "blue");
}
```

Could you tell me how we can successfully load all data of CSS into Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried ```getComputedStyle```? **Edit** Only issue with this approach is that you'd have to check the rgb value rather than the name of the colour.

Comment: The `style` object on an element node only shows styles *directly* coded into the HTML for that element. Styles implied by CSS rules have to be fetched via `getComputedStyle()` (and I think something similar but different in older IE versions).

Comment: @Gingercook your issue is similar to the following thread [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks everyone it helped really :). I upped all of you who shared their knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a messy-ish solution that I've cooked together using an array of different answers to similar questions I've seen on here...

This solution converts the rgb value to a hex value and the colour name to the hex value, then it compares the hex values, nothing mind blowing. Maybe a little messy, but hey, it works!

### Edit

You need to do something *similar* to this simply because using the `getComputedStyle` will return `rgb(0, 0, 255)` and of course comparing that to a string `blue` just won't work. Therefore you need a way to convert both values so that they can be compared, i.e. `blue` is in **fact** equal to `rgb(0, 0, 255)` but of course, JavaScript won't automatically know that...

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", toggleMe);

var rgbToHex = function(rgb) {

  var hexDigits = new Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

  //Function to convert rgb color to hex format
  function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
  }

  function hex(x) {
    return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
  }
  return rgb2hex(rgb);
};

function colourNameToHex(colour) {
  var colours = {
    "aliceblue": "#f0f8ff",
    "antiquewhite": "#faebd7",
    "aqua": "#00ffff",
    "aquamarine": "#7fffd4",
    "azure": "#f0ffff",
    "beige": "#f5f5dc",
    "bisque": "#ffe4c4",
    "black": "#000000",
    "blanchedalmond": "#ffebcd",
    "blue": "#0000ff",
    "blueviolet": "#8a2be2",
    "brown": "#a52a2a",
    "burlywood": "#deb887",
    "cadetblue": "#5f9ea0",
    "chartreuse": "#7fff00",
    "chocolate": "#d2691e",
    "coral": "#ff7f50",
    "cornflowerblue": "#6495ed",
    "cornsilk": "#fff8dc",
    "crimson": "#dc143c",
    "cyan": "#00ffff",
    "darkblue": "#00008b",
    "darkcyan": "#008b8b",
    "darkgoldenrod": "#b8860b",
    "darkgray": "#a9a9a9",
    "darkgreen": "#006400",
    "darkkhaki": "#bdb76b",
    "darkmagenta": "#8b008b",
    "darkolivegreen": "#556b2f",
    "darkorange": "#ff8c00",
    "darkorchid": "#9932cc",
    "darkred": "#8b0000",
    "darksalmon": "#e9967a",
    "darkseagreen": "#8fbc8f",
    "darkslateblue": "#483d8b",
    "darkslategray": "#2f4f4f",
    "darkturquoise": "#00ced1",
    "darkviolet": "#9400d3",
    "deeppink": "#ff1493",
    "deepskyblue": "#00bfff",
    "dimgray": "#696969",
    "dodgerblue": "#1e90ff",
    "firebrick": "#b22222",
    "floralwhite": "#fffaf0",
    "forestgreen": "#228b22",
    "fuchsia": "#ff00ff",
    "gainsboro": "#dcdcdc",
    "ghostwhite": "#f8f8ff",
    "gold": "#ffd700",
    "goldenrod": "#daa520",
    "gray": "#808080",
    "green": "#008000",
    "greenyellow": "#adff2f",
    "honeydew": "#f0fff0",
    "hotpink": "#ff69b4",
    "indianred ": "#cd5c5c",
    "indigo": "#4b0082",
    "ivory": "#fffff0",
    "khaki": "#f0e68c",
    "lavender": "#e6e6fa",
    "lavenderblush": "#fff0f5",
    "lawngreen": "#7cfc00",
    "lemonchiffon": "#fffacd",
    "lightblue": "#add8e6",
    "lightcoral": "#f08080",
    "lightcyan": "#e0ffff",
    "lightgoldenrodyellow": "#fafad2",
    "lightgrey": "#d3d3d3",
    "lightgreen": "#90ee90",
    "lightpink": "#ffb6c1",
    "lightsalmon": "#ffa07a",
    "lightseagreen": "#20b2aa",
    "lightskyblue": "#87cefa",
    "lightslategray": "#778899",
    "lightsteelblue": "#b0c4de",
    "lightyellow": "#ffffe0",
    "lime": "#00ff00",
    "limegreen": "#32cd32",
    "linen": "#faf0e6",
    "magenta": "#ff00ff",
    "maroon": "#800000",
    "mediumaquamarine": "#66cdaa",
    "mediumblue": "#0000cd",
    "mediumorchid": "#ba55d3",
    "mediumpurple": "#9370d8",
    "mediumseagreen": "#3cb371",
    "mediumslateblue": "#7b68ee",
    "mediumspringgreen": "#00fa9a",
    "mediumturquoise": "#48d1cc",
    "mediumvioletred": "#c71585",
    "midnightblue": "#191970",
    "mintcream": "#f5fffa",
    "mistyrose": "#ffe4e1",
    "moccasin": "#ffe4b5",
    "navajowhite": "#ffdead",
    "navy": "#000080",
    "oldlace": "#fdf5e6",
    "olive": "#808000",
    "olivedrab": "#6b8e23",
    "orange": "#ffa500",
    "orangered": "#ff4500",
    "orchid": "#da70d6",
    "palegoldenrod": "#eee8aa",
    "palegreen": "#98fb98",
    "paleturquoise": "#afeeee",
    "palevioletred": "#d87093",
    "papayawhip": "#ffefd5",
    "peachpuff": "#ffdab9",
    "peru": "#cd853f",
    "pink": "#ffc0cb",
    "plum": "#dda0dd",
    "powderblue": "#b0e0e6",
    "purple": "#800080",
    "rebeccapurple": "#663399",
    "red": "#ff0000",
    "rosybrown": "#bc8f8f",
    "royalblue": "#4169e1",
    "saddlebrown": "#8b4513",
    "salmon": "#fa8072",
    "sandybrown": "#f4a460",
    "seagreen": "#2e8b57",
    "seashell": "#fff5ee",
    "sienna": "#a0522d",
    "silver": "#c0c0c0",
    "skyblue": "#87ceeb",
    "slateblue": "#6a5acd",
    "slategray": "#708090",
    "snow": "#fffafa",
    "springgreen": "#00ff7f",
    "steelblue": "#4682b4",
    "tan": "#d2b48c",
    "teal": "#008080",
    "thistle": "#d8bfd8",
    "tomato": "#ff6347",
    "turquoise": "#40e0d0",
    "violet": "#ee82ee",
    "wheat": "#f5deb3",
    "white": "#ffffff",
    "whitesmoke": "#f5f5f5",
    "yellow": "#ffff00",
    "yellowgreen": "#9acd32"
  };

  if (typeof colours[colour.toLowerCase()] != 'undefined')
    return colours[colour.toLowerCase()];

  return false;
}

function toggleMe() {
  alert(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("test")).display == "block");
  alert(rgbToHex(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("test")).color) == colourNameToHex("blue"));
  console.log(rgbToHex(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("test")).color));
  console.log(colourNameToHex("blue"));
}
```

```css
#test {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="test">This is an example</p>
    <button type="button" id="myButton">Click</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```