# JavaScript for changing a <div> colour from a button press

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I'm a little unsure why my code doesn't seem to be working when my html and JS code are within the same file. When the html and JS are separate, seems to be working fine. Can someone point out the error in my ways....I'm a newbie!!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <button onclick="chngCol()" id="burn">Burn!</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
chngCol() {
    if(document.getElementByClass('light').style.background == "#00ffff")
      { 
       document.getElementByClass('light').style.background = "#ffff00"; 
      } 
       else if(document.getElementByClass('light').style.background == "ffff00")
      {
       document.getElementByClass('light').style.background = "#ff00ff"; 
      }
       else if(document.getElementByClass('light').style.background == "#ff00ff")
      { 
       document.getElementByClass('light').style.background = "#00ffff";       
      }
   }
```

**CSS:**

```
    .light{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color:#00ffff;
    }
```

All code is in the same document with the appropriate  tags and  however the error i'm getting in Chrome Console on the first { after calling chngCol.

Comment: There's no jQuery in the code posted, and `document.getElementByClass()` does not exist.

Comment: and `chngCol() {` is not valid JS. Either `function chngCol() {` OR `const chngCol = () => {`

Comment: Hi @Pointy apologies JavaScript* I meant, (updated).

Comment: I cannot believe I missed it, thank you @mplungjan I forgot function BEFORE!!! Thank you all!

Comment: Also, if the style is set in the stylesheet `.style` not get it - you will need `getComputedStyle` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Thanks @Pete I'll take a look at that now, however if CSS was external as it normally would be, I guess the .style would be ok?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a multitude of issues.

- `chngCol() {` is not valid JS. Either `function chngCol() {` OR `const chngCol = () =>`
- You need `document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0]` OR better, `document.querySelector(".light")`
- You cannot read the background color of the element if it is not set in script first.

I think you meant to do this:

```js
let cnt = 0;
const colors = ["#00ffff", "#ffff00", "#ff00ff"];
const chngCol = () => {
  cnt++;
  if (cnt >= colors.length) cnt = 0; // wrap
  document.querySelector('.light').style.background = colors[cnt]; // use the array
}
document.getElementById("burn").addEventListener("click", chngCol);
```

```css
.light {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
}

#burn {
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="light"></div>
  <button id="burn">Burn!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan I took your 2nd bullet point and worked :-)

Comment: @K.Haydock You are welcome. Do please study my example since it is  unobtrusive and DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Answer (score 0):

The document.getElementByClass selector is an array selector. In order to select your element you should select the first element of the array.
Try this instead:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('light')[0].style.background
```

Comment: Should this not be `getElementsByClassName` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName