# Grabbing the CSS of an HTML text selection using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection, textselection

I am [creating a text editor](https://nottimtam.github.io/LightP) using HTML, CSS, and JS. I've got most of the functions worked out, and even though it is deprecated, I've been using `document.execCommand()` to stylize text content in a `contenteditable` div. I have a hotbar at the top of the screen that has all the buttons to change the font, change the size, bold, italic, underline etc. Similarly to google docs, I would like the top bar to update its values to match those of whatever text is selected. I've got a function that grabs the HTML of a text selection thanks to another post on this site:

```
function getHTMLOfSelection () {
    var range;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.htmlText;
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
            return div.innerHTML;
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to grab the css of the whole thing. For instance, if half the selection is Arial font, and the other is Serif. I want it to pick the first. But I don't even know how to start with getting the CSS. Here is what I have so far:

```
function updateControlBar() {
    selection = getHTMLOfSelection();
    if (typeof selection != "undefined") {
        // Get the selection's font and update the font menu to show it.
        document.getElementById('font-button').value = selection.fontFamily;
        document.getElementById('font-button').style.fontFamily = selection.fontFamily;
        console.log(selection.fontFamily);
    } else {
        console.log("No selection, cannot update control bar values.");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the following SO help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can now use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Try the following:

```
var bEl =  document.querySelector("body"); 
getComputedStyle(bEl);
```

You'll see :

I ran it on this page (via console) and I saw over 400 css properties listed.

> CSS2Properties(486)