# Does display:none have different meaning in html and in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following html.

```
<div id="test" style="display:none"></div>
<script> console.log(document.getElementById("test").style.display) </script>
```

This results in `none` in the console log. However, if instead:

```
<style> #test{ display: none; } </style>
<div id="test"></div>
<script> console.log(document.getElementById("test").style.display) </script>
```

then it fails to determine the display property. Why is that the case?

Comment: You should test your code, it works for two different cases. I see none twice when I run your code.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: The meaning as far as not displaying the element is the same but if the setting is through a style sheet the style attribute of the element isn’t changed it has to be set explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the style of an element in javascript via `element.style` only works, when the style is set inline.

Otherwise, if the style is set in a css file or with the `<style></style>` tag, you have to use the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method.

You can find further information [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript) SO question!

Comment: Happen to have just finished reading the links when I see your answer...! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Meaning in html and css is the same
But for this type of problem you need to use `getComputedStyle()`

Example:

```js
const computedStyles = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("test"))
console.log(computedStyles.display)
```