# Javascript document.querySelector just need the value

Tags: javascript, queryselector

my webpage excerpt looks like this

```
<div class="current-timestamp" style="--duration:"00:13:19"; --absolute-position:"00:00:00";"><span class="position"></span><span class="divider"></span><span class="duration"></span></div>
```

i try to get the value 00:13:19 via the chrome console with this command

> document.querySelector(".current-timestamp");

however i receive the full code like above.

What do i need to do to just receive "00:13:19" ?

Comment: I think you'd need to retrieve and parse the div's style attribute.

Comment: Use window.getComputedStyle to access the CSS custom property.

Comment: Detailed information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript

Comment: If you want to access these data from JavaScript then add them as data attributes, they are easy to access, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not common to store the value of a component in a CSS variable like you have done, however it can be accessed in the following way:

```js
getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".current-timestamp")).getPropertyValue("--duration");
```

Essentially, we are getting the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) of the element in question, and then using `getPropertyValue` to get the value of the duration variable on the element.

However, I would highly advise against using CSS variables for storing non-style related values in the future.

Edit: This can actually be done using the style property directly, as this is set on the element itself:

```
document.querySelector(".current-timestamp").style.getPropertyValue("--duration");
```