# Javascript 100% width of an Element

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi is there any way to check if an element like a progress bar has 100% width?

I've tried this but it does not work

```
let i = 0;
function start() {
    if (i == 0){
        i = 1;
        let elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
        let width = 10;
        let id =  setInterval(frame, 60);

        function frame() {
            if (elem.getAttribute("width") >= '100 %') {
                document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
                clearInterval(id);
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
html Code:

```
<div id ="myProgress">
   <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 100% width relative to what?

Comment: relative to the whole screen (browser window). Is it possible?

Comment: Okay, can you add the html ?

Comment: It is bad practice to create logic that is based on the state of HTML elements. State should be created using variables in JavaScript, then you can add logic to alter these variables, and then set the properties of the HTML elements to appear according to that state.

Comment: As Peter already suggested, rethink your approach. Your logic should not be dependent on a style property value. Ask yourself,: 1: do I get that progress value already from somewhere? If not, can that plugin, method or API expose that value? 2: Once I get that 0..100 value how do I perform an action at 100?

Comment: Could you explain what is that you're actually building and trying to achieve? What's the context of your problem? If not explained this is more like an [**XY-Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I want to make a quiz game and i want to build in a progress bar, when the progress bar is full i want to submit a form so that the there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need raw property from style use `element.style.width` it will return string value (if setted through style attribute). If you need result value use `window.getComputedStyle(element).width` this will returns value in px

relates to:
[How to get an HTML element's style values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Just don't use this suggestion for the afore-mentioned reasons. **Never** make logic dependent on style values. It should be the other way around.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan it depends, sure that we can find N different ways but every solution has pros and cons. Sometimes it's better to do straight forward without overthinking. I have suggested how to get style property from JavaScript, it may be usefully for other who will see this question (because question about how to get width). But I agree that we always should be aware about impact.

Answer (score 0):

Empty divs won't take space by default, you either need to add content inside it, or use CSS

Additionally `if (elem.getAttribute("width") >= '100 %')` should be `if (width >= 100)`

```js
function start() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  let width = 10;
  let id = setInterval(frame, 60);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      // document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
      clearInterval(id);
      width = 10;
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

start()
```

```css
#myProgress {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

#myBar {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 0%
}

#myBar:after {
  content: '\200b';
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will run the if section even if there is no progress bar. And i wanted to avoid this. Is there any other way to realize this?

Comment: `width` is the state, `i` is not even needed it can be removed

Comment: what does the #myBar:after {
  content: '\200b';
} 
do?

Comment: Like said in first line, *Empty divs won't take space by default, you either need to add content inside it, or use CSS* - `\200b` is a zero width space