# can a javascript get the value of the div width from a css file

Tags: javascript

can a javascript get the value of the div width from a css file,

if yes, then please tell me how :)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "from a CSS file"? Why not just query the `div`'s real width in the DOM?

Comment: as i want to change the width of div in different templates

Comment: Looks like you want to get the *computed style*, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531737/javascript-incapable-of-getting-elements-max-height-via-element-style-maxheight

Answer (score 3):

CSS files TELL what to set.  The DOM (Document Object Model) HAS what it is currently which is the document.

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width); // removes the "px" at the end
```

Makes the assumption your have a div with id="mydiv"

edit1: There are also these:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").clientWidth;
document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth;
```

Edit2: just because it will probably come up: offsetWidth will include the width of any borders, horizontal padding, vertical scrollbar width, etc.

Comment: It is possible that div does not exits on page. So, question's author can create dom element with required attributes (for css); calculate width; remove dom element.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for some of the methods/properties associated with the `StyleSheetList` object stored in the `document.styleSheets` property.

See:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml