# c# web browser get value of progressbar?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

So I am trying to do something whilst the progressbar is not 0%. Example

```
var status = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("counter");
if(counter.width > 0%)
{
//CODE
}
```

And here is the HTML for the bar

```
 < div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" id="counter" style="width: 0%;"></div>
```

As you might've guess, it's the "width" I want to keep updated but I dont really know how, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `counter.style.width`?

Comment: some more details are required. the progress bar is in webpage?

Comment: run a timer in your c# code. For each timer trigger event get the current progressbar percentage completed.  then do the required task.

Comment: you wanna read width property of HTML element?

Comment: function getPerventage { return document.getElementById("counter").offsetWidth;}

Comment: call this method from your c#

Comment: @null1941 Did'nt work :( there is no method called "offsetWidth"

Comment: try document.getElementById("yourDiv").clientWidth;

Comment: @null1941 Sadly no... I used this to get textbox value "            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("betAmount").SetAttribute("value", bet.ToString());" I tried converting with no success...

Comment: bro.. can you paste your html page here?  try this document.getElementById("yourDiv")[0].offsetWidth

Comment: @null1941 I dont own the website, Im just trying to extract some information from it, I already posted the HTML code they use for the progressBar at the question.

Comment: what you want to read? You want to read the width of that tag or you want to set width to that tag?

Comment: @null1941 I dont really need to ready anything, I just need to call an if statement if the "width:" hits example 70%, so the code would be "< div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" id="counter" style="width: 70%;"></div>"

Comment: where is this if statement is present? in c#

Comment: @null1941 Sorry didn't quite get your question.

Comment: you said you want to call and if statement right? Where is this if statement present? is it present in html page javascript ? or  is it in c#?

Comment: @null1941 Oh! It is in C#, making a small little application.

Comment: ok.. that c# does't magically knows about the progress happening in html page. For this start a timer or loop in c#. Keep checking whether progress crossed 70% or not. If it crosses the do whatever required.  No question again are you able to get the progress?

Comment: @null1941 I already am doing this, but I was wondering if I should use .InnerHTML or .InnerText

Comment: are you able to get the progress? I am not understanding why you wanna use InnerHTML or InnerText?

Comment: @null1941 No, I do not get any progress at the moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103278/can-a-javascript-get-the-value-of-the-div-width-from-a-css-file

Comment: @null1941 That is Javascript or I'am missing something since .clientWidth does not exist for me and returns an error.

Comment: yes that is javascript. You should put this function  "function getPerventage { return document.getElementById("counter").offsetWidth;} " in that HTML page inside script tag. then call this method from c#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437251/calling-a-javascript-function-in-the-c-sharp-webbrowser-control

Comment: @null1941 I cant edit the website, Im just extracting information from it.

Comment: Ok then.. try load that page in webbrowser control the once it loaded inject the function which i menctioned

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control/154496#154496

Comment: after injection this .. try call the injected method to get the width

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing approach to the problem, found a hidden value not visible for normal users and used that to confirm information.

```
            var checkValue = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_progressValue");

            if (checkValue.InnerText == value)
            {
                //code
            }
```