# window.getComputedStyle return CSS max-height with unresolved calc() function

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a problem with function from topic in my Angular project. I have this code:

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this.frontLayer.nativeElement).maxHeight);
```

and in component template:

```
 <div #frontLayer        
      [style.maxHeight]="maxHeight"
      [style.height]="curHeight"
      [style.minHeight]="minHeight">
```

The `maxHeight` property is set in ngOnInit.

Unfortunately, result that I receive is unresolved and looks like this:

```
calc(100% - 56px)
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `max-height` is not computed in most browsers except `edge`/`internet explorer` so its better to compute the height instead, but since the question deals with checking the max height, below is my workaround/hackish solution!

**Height 100% refers to the parent height when position is relative for the child, so we get the height of the parent container, then minus the 56 to get the final value!**

We should just use `height` property, since `max-height` is not computed.

[SO reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531737/javascript-incapable-of-getting-elements-max-height-via-element-style-maxheight)

Hackish solution!

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [
    `
  .parent {
    height:500px;
  }
  `,
  ],
  template: `
  <div class="parent">
    <div #frontLayer  class="measure-height"       
      [style.maxHeight]="maxHeight"
      [style.height]="curHeight"
      [style.minHeight]="minHeight">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  maxHeight = 'calc(100% - 56px)';
  curHeight = 'calc(100% - 56px)';
  minHeight = 'calc(100% - 56px)';
  @ViewChild('frontLayer') frontLayer!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  name = 'Angular';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this.frontLayer.nativeElement);
    // since max-height is a range it does not
    console.log('not working', this.frontLayer.nativeElement.style.minHeight); // issue replicated
    console.log('not working', compStyles.getPropertyValue('max-height')); // issue replicated
    console.log('working', compStyles.getPropertyValue('height')); // we can access the height instead to get the pixel value
    console.log(
      'working',
      this.frontLayer.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height
    ); //  another method to access the height calculated!
    // workaround way to calculate max-height, but only works if frontLayer div is position: relative!
    // get the parent height:
    if (this.frontLayer?.nativeElement?.parentElement) {
      const clientRectParent =
        this.frontLayer?.nativeElement?.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const parentHeight = clientRectParent.height;
      const maxHeightCalculated = Math.max(0, parentHeight - 56);
      console.log('hackish calculation of max-height', maxHeightCalculated);
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jhbwgx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)