Multiple accordions working independently where the first of every accordion is open
I'm using this accordion module from W3Schools: https://codepen.io/SupposedlySam/details/oWWgqZ
It's working well, only a problem occurs when i use two of them on the page. They still work. Only they work as one. What i want is that the two work independently. Which means the first tab of both is opened. Now only the first of all tabs is open. When i open a tab in Accordion 2 the first accordion closes, which shouldn't be the case as well.
I'm using the code in combination with ACF repeater. Code showing here is just pure HTML.
Does someone know how to do it? Thanks in advance!
Code:
HTML + PHP:
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <h3>Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <h3>Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

JS:
// W3C's JS Code
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

// Open the first accordion
var firstAccordion = acc[0];
var firstPanel = firstAccordion.nextElementSibling;
firstAccordion.classList.add("active");
firstPanel.style.maxHeight = firstPanel.scrollHeight + "px";

// Add onclick listener to every accordion element
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    // For toggling purposes detect if the clicked section is already "active"
    var isActive = this.classList.contains("active");

    // Close all accordions
    var allAccordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for (j = 0; j < allAccordions.length; j++) {
      // Remove active class from section header
      allAccordions[j].classList.remove("active");

      // Remove the max-height class from the panel to close it
      var panel = allAccordions[j].nextElementSibling;
      var maxHeightValue = getStyle(panel, "maxHeight");

      if (maxHeightValue !== "0px") {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
    }

    // Toggle the clicked section using a ternary operator
    isActive ? this.classList.remove("active") : this.classList.add("active");

    // Toggle the panel element
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    var maxHeightValue = getStyle(panel, "maxHeight");

    if (maxHeightValue !== "0px") {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  };
}

// Cross-browser way to get the computed height of a certain element. Credit to @CMS on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2531934/7926565)
function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
  var value, defaultView = (el.ownerDocument || document).defaultView;
  // W3C standard way:
  if (defaultView && defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    // sanitize property name to css notation
    // (hypen separated words eg. font-Size)
    styleProp = styleProp.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();
    return defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  } else if (el.currentStyle) { // IE
    // sanitize property name to camelCase
    styleProp = styleProp.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter) {
      return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
    value = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    // convert other units to pixels on IE
    if (/^\d+(em|pt|%|ex)?$/i.test(value)) {
      return (function(value) {
        var oldLeft = el.style.left,
          oldRsLeft = el.runtimeStyle.left;
        el.runtimeStyle.left = el.currentStyle.left;
        el.style.left = value || 0;
        value = el.style.pixelLeft + "px";
        el.style.left = oldLeft;
        el.runtimeStyle.left = oldRsLeft;
        return value;
      })(value);
    }
    return value;
  }
}

CSS:
button.accordion {
  //background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background: none;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  //background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:before {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  //float: right;
  //margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button.accordion.active:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  //background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


wrap each "group" of accordions in a div and then add/alter this var parent = this.parentElement;       var allAccordions = n.getElementsByClassName("accordion"); then it should work

in CSS // for comments are not valid.  use only /* ..... */

in HTML5 you must use <details> element for accordion  see sample code for this spefic usage.  less code, simple to understand, efficient...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai/56194608#56194608

To effectively make 2 accordions work independently on the page the javascript logic must be scoped to handle them separately.
HTML:
 <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="col-5">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p><?php the_sub_field('content'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p><?php the_sub_field('content'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="col-5">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p><?php the_sub_field('content'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <button class="accordion"><h4><?php the_sub_field('titel'); ?></h4><br /></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p><?php the_sub_field('content'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

JS modification:
    <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var accordionContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-container');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(accordionContainers, function(container) {
    var acc = container.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

    if (acc.length > 0) {
        var firstAccordion = acc[0];
        var firstPanel = firstAccordion.nextElementSibling;
        firstAccordion.classList.add("active");
        firstPanel.style.maxHeight = firstPanel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
            var isActive = this.classList.contains("active");

            var allAccordions = container.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            for (var j = 0; j < allAccordions.length; j++) {
                allAccordions[j].classList.remove("active");
                var panel = allAccordions[j].nextElementSibling;
                var maxHeightValue = getStyle(panel, "maxHeight");
                if (maxHeightValue !== "0px") {
                    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                }
            }

            isActive ? this.classList.remove("active") : this.classList.add("active");

            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            var maxHeightValue = getStyle(panel, "maxHeight");
            if (maxHeightValue !== "0px") {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        };
    }
});

function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
    var value, defaultView = (el.ownerDocument || document).defaultView;
    if (defaultView && defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        styleProp = styleProp.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();
        return defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    } else if (el.currentStyle) {
        styleProp = styleProp.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
        value = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
        if (/^\d+(em|pt|%|ex)?$/i.test(value)) {
            return (function(value) {
                var oldLeft = el.style.left, oldRsLeft = el.runtimeStyle.left;
                el.runtimeStyle.left = el.currentStyle.left;
                el.style.left = value || 0;
                value = el.style.pixelLeft + "px";
                el.style.left = oldLeft;
                el.runtimeStyle.left = oldRsLeft;
                return value;
            })(value);
        }

       return value;
        }
    }
});
</script>


Super, you're a hero :)
